# How to embed fonts when exporting Mathematica graphics as PDF

Tags: export, fonts, pdf-format

Upon exporting a Mathematica graphics expression as a PDF, Mathematica does not seem to embed any nonstandard fonts used. When you open the resulting PDF document with a PDF viewer, all the text items are rendered with standard fonts instead.

Is there a way to make Mathematica embed nonstandard fonts?

Example with Mathematica 8.0.4 under Mac OS X 10.7:

```
g = Graphics[{ Circle[], 
   Text["Sample", 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Papyrus", FontWeight -> "Bold", 
      FontSize -> 24}]}, ImageSize -> Tiny]
f = Export["~/Desktop/Graphics.PDF", g, "PDF"]
```

The resulting PDF does not use the correct font.

Comment: Can you give a code example, and instructions for checking that the fonts are embedded?  I tried `Export["testpdf.pdf", 
 Graphics@Text[Style["asd", FontFamily -> "Candara", FontSize -> 50]]]` and Adobe Reader reports that the font is embedded.  I used CTRL-D in Adobe Reader, and clicked the Fonts tab.  It says, "Candara (Embedded)".

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: Sakra, what font *version* of Papyrus and what format is it? You can check this in Fontbook. I think it matters.

Comment: `Font Book.app` says Version 6.1d10e2.

Comment: In Linux (Mathematica version 12.1.0) the embedding does not work as tested with the Export/Import example...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What Verbeia said in her answer is not entirely correct — Mathematica indeed does embed the font, regardless of whether a particular font weight/slant exists or not. The real culprits are the PDF viewers on Macs, which do not use the base font if the specified weight is not available. It took some digging around to get to the reason though. The clues that led to my reasoning are as follows:

1. **Mathematica knows what font it used when you re-import**
   This was the first clue. Executing `Import["~/Desktop/Graphics.PDF"]` will correctly display the graphics in Papyrus font, albeit without the bold option (which, as Verbeia noted, doesn't exist in all fonts). So the information had to be in the file *somewhere*.

   [image]
2. **The binary file shows Papyrus embedded in it**
   Opening the pdf in vim under hex mode, you find the font info embedded in it. What you see in the readable text on the right is the full copyright info, which they'd have to include only if it were embedded.

   [image]
3. **It opens correctly on linux systems**
   Papyrus is *not* a font that comes installed by default with linux systems. The above file opens with the correct font (but not weight) on RHEL 6 and Ubuntu 11.10, which can only mean that the font is embedded in the pdf. Below is a screenshot in RHEL 6, with the same file opened in Adobe reader (left) and evince (right).

   [image]
4. **Hey, it opens perfectly in Adobe Reader!**
   Below is a screenshot of the same file opened in Adobe reader (left) and Preview.app (right). You can see that Adobe sure does know which font to use.

   [image]

So you can see here that the problem is most likely with the PDF viewers on macs (other than Adobe reader). My guess is that they don't stay true to Adobe's specifications, and instead rely on OSX's Quartz framework for rendering the file, which is why you don't see the right font.

Either that, or they don't like the fact that Mathematica uses PDF v1.4 to export its files. v1.4 is pretty old (2001), and it is worth mentioning (since you're embedding non-standard fonts) that PDF v1.4 **does not** support embedding "Open Type" fonts. That was introduced only in v1.6, and if you're working with such fonts, you might want to keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for digging that out. I only use Preview.app for PDF viewing     under Mac OS X.

Comment: @R.M Aren't you saying, though, that Adobe Reader doesn't so much 'use the correct font' as 'guess correctly what Mathematica got up to when it created the file', and then cover for it? Technically Mathematica specified a font that didn't exist, and just drew a black line around the font to make it look bold. But Preview refused to make a font up this way, and defaulted to something it did have. If you ask for Papyrus Italic, Mathematica can do that too...

Perhaps Preview should loosen up and play a little bit more!

Comment: @R.M this answer is incorrect and misleading. The presence of the font name in the PDF file does not mean that the font itself is embedded in the file, which was the OP's question. Adobe Reader and Mathematica display the re-imported graphic correctly because you have the font installed. If you displayed the graphic on a computer that did not have the font installed, the bold version would not display but the normal weight one would. (Though strangely, now that I check this on my Mac *it does embed*, even though similar fonts on Windows don't. The format of the font might matter as well.)

Comment: @Verbeia I don't follow your comment... you start out saying it isn't embedded, but ultimately agree with me in saying that it is indeed embedded. Which one is it? It is incorrect to say that the font is not embedded just because it doesn't have a bold option. As I said in my answer (but didn't make it explicit) I tested it on ubuntu 11.10 and it opens with the correct font. Papyrus is a font that is shipped only with Windows and OS X, not linux distros, and this can only mean that the font was embedded.

Comment: @Verbeia I've clarified that it does indeed open correctly on machines that _don't_ have the font installed – I'll maybe include screenshots when I get to those machines again. You should probably test that out yourself before saying it's incorrect. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was there in the earlier revisions, but the link accidentally got deleted during my last update. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Excellent post, now complete. +1

Comment: @R.M - only that your answer did not include any tests of whether the font had actully been embedded. (ok the Linux view is a test.) The name of the font will still be included in the PDF file if the font is not embedded, and the PDF will then substitute the font if it is not on the system. I demonstrated this with another font. It looks like there is more to the problem than my answer, because on my Mac, and it seems on yours, Papyrus Bold does embed. This could be something to do with font formats. But there is something to what I showed in my ansewr.

Comment: @Verbeia I added screenshots of the file opened in linux in two different pdf viewers. Since you have access to both Windows and Mac machines, could you try saving with "Kristen ITC" on windows and opening it in Mac (I'm sure that font doesn't exist on a Mac, but in case it does on yours, please try with one that doesn't). The font name definitely is included in the pdf if it doesn't exist, but it looks a lot different in the hex view than if it were embedded.

Comment: Ok I have removed the downvote. But I think that both answers contain part of the truth. There clearly are fonts that don't embed properly, even if they exist, or [this question would not have come up](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/736/8). And even though Papyrus Bold works in some PDF viewers, it is fair to say that font weights that don't exist can't be relied on. It is not clear to me that Preview's behaviour is incorrect. There seems to be a subtle relationship between font format and how it exports, which needs further investigation.

Answer (score 12):

Mathematica will normally embed the fonts correctly in a PDF. But this only works if the font exists. Papyrus does not have a bold weight. Try with `FontWeight->"Bold"` deleted and see if this works.

I don't have Papyrus on my Windows machine, but I checked that Kristen ITC does not embed if it is bold, and does if the `FontWeight` option is removed.

[image] [image]

Comment: By the way @sakra, thank you for this question. I didn't actually know the answer to this, and your question made me find it out. Very useful.

Comment: +1 that is interesting that it doesn't embed if the font weight for that font isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica 9, (rm -rf)'s comment that fonts with the extension `.otf` (aka OpenType) can't be embedded still holds. In addition, I've also noticed that not all fonts with the extension `.ttf` can be embedded.

When choosing a font for your PDF files, it might be best to always test the files in other environments where that font isn't installed.

Comment: This seems to be the issue in Mathematica 10.2 as well.