# $\LaTeX$ and Mathematica

Tags: graphics, export, latex

I quite often would like to draw graphics in my $\LaTeX$ documents using Mathematica. I have encountered three problems. I would like to know if there are any workarounds to these problems

I would like to make my graphics homogeneous with my document. That means that I would like to use the same font in the graphics (labels for axis etc) as the main text. Mathematica does not support Computer Modern. I found a workaround using PSFrag, saving graphics as EPS. It is possible using PSfrag to rename the text in the graphic into $\LaTeX$ code. A big downside is that this method does not allow me to use pdflatex. Many other packages (hyperlink) therefore do not work.

`Graphics3D` objects are extremely big. If I save it using a bitmap, the picture usually becomes horrible.

I often would like to use transparency. If I use `Opacity` to make some part of the graphic transparent, the exported file in Mathematica is horrible.

Comment: Theoretically you *can* get Mathematica to use Computer Modern, but it's a lot of trouble for little gain an imperfect results.  You could start by downloading [Latin Modern in OpenType format](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download).  Mathematica exports to PDF 1.4, a PDF specification too old to be able to embed OpenType fonts, so you'd need to convert them to TrueType.  Then install the appropriate font (e.g. "LM Roman 10" is upright, optimized for 10 pt viewing), and make the plot with `BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 10", FontSize -> 10}`.

Comment: This is not a satisfactory answer I know, but I thought it would be good to write it down.  Even if you do this, mathematical text (formulae) won't appear in the same style as when typeset by LaTeX, you unless all you need is numbers for the axes, it's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: For `Graphics3D` objects, there is the Fortran code [Polygone](http://www-staff.lboro.ac.uk/~mait/personal2/polygone/polygone.html) that reduces the size of postscript graphics by merging unnecessary polygons.

Comment: @Simon that could have been a good answer for my question here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/644/how-can-all-those-tiny-polygons-generated-by-regionplot-be-joined-into-a-single  I encourage you to post it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: problem is, I've never used Polygone - only heard about others using it. If you get it working and post an answer, I promise to upvote it!

Comment: Personally I use Mathematica to generate data for the plots, and then create the plots themselves using a LaTeX package like PGFPlots.  A couple extra steps, sure, but I like the extra control that you get.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are a few different parts to your question. I'll just answer the part about using `psfrag`and `pdflatex`.

There's a package called [pstool](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstool) that automates the whole process of using `psfrag` with `pdflatex`.

For example, here's a graphics created in Mathematica 8

```
plot = Plot[Sin[Exp[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"e", "s"}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "plot.eps", plot]
```

[image: da plot]

Note the use of the single character names for the axes. This was discussed in the stackexchange question 
[Mathematica 8.0 and psfrag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6384887/421225).

You can use psfrag on this image and compile straight to pdf using the following latex file

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}
\psfragfig{plot}{%
 \psfrag{e}{$\epsilon$}
 \psfrag{s}{$\Sigma$}}  
\end{document}
```

Compile it using `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`. You can optionally include a file `plot.tex` in the same directory which can contain all the `psfrag` code for `plot.eps` so that your main `.tex` file is tidier and the `plot` is more portable.
Here's a screenshot of the graphics in the pdf file:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't use LaTeX so this is solely out of curiosity but I notice that the conversion also converted the axes labels. Presumably that is to do with default fonts or something?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch : The conversion happens with `\psfrag{e}{$\epsilon$}` in the LaTeX file.

Comment: It is probably worth pointing out that pstools and psfrag do not work in MMA10.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick If you look at the generated eps you can see that the fonts are by default outlined and not represented as text. This is probably a bug and will hopefully be fixed. See [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61878/font-difference-in-mathematica-9-and-10-after-export-to-illustrator#comment-175814) by Szabolcs

Comment: Hi! I do as you say (except the part "Compile it using pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex." which I don't understand) and the output simply writes "e" and "s" and not "\epsilon" and "\Sigma" on the axes. Is it the part that I don't get that messes things up?

Comment: @Thankyouforyourcooperation - It looks like Mathematica is still converting text to outlines (as mentioned in a comment above). Until they fix this psfrag won't work. 
I just submitted feedback on this issue, asking that the option TextOutlines works for EPS like it does for PDF export.

Comment: @Simon ok good job. Hope it will work out for the better.

Answer (score 99):

[image: Join the chat at https://gitter.im/MaTeX-help/Lobby]
[image: GitHub (pre-)release]
[image: Github All Releases]
[image: Contributions welcome]
[image: DOI]

> I would like to make my graphics homogeneous with my (LaTeX) document. That means that I would like to use the same font in the graphics (labels for axis etc) as the main text.

[I recently wrote a package, called MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX), to solve this exact problem.  MaTeX makes it easy to compile short LaTeX snippets and embed them in Mathematica notebooks or graphics.

**Tip:** MaTeX comes with integrated documentation that contains many examples and a full tutorial. After installing the package, go to Help → Wolfram Documentation, and search for "MaTeX".

Here's a quick demo:

```
<< MaTeX`

MaTeX["\\sin^2 \\varphi + \\cos^2 \\varphi = 1", Magnification -> 2]

MaTeX[Sin[x] + O[x]^8, Magnification -> 2]
```

[image]

```
funs = {Sin[x], Normal[Sin[x] + O[x]^8]};

Plot[Evaluate[funs], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> MaTeX /@ funs, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> BlackFrame]
```

[image]

I use it in conjunction with the [Latin Modern fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) to achieve a consistent visual style. (Note: These fonts are accessible under different names on different operating systems. Check your font manager for the correct name.)

> I found a workaround using PSFrag, saving graphics as EPS. It is possible using PSfrag to rename the text in the graphic into LATEX code. A big downside is that this method does not allow me to use pdflatex.

[You can still use pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=psfrag+pdflatex+is%3Aquestion), but it comes with inconveniences.  MaTeX solves this problem completely.

Another Mathematica package I learned about just after releasing MaTeX is [MathPSfrag](http://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/), which relies on PSfrag and should be able to create PDF output.  However, I have never used it.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that you can load any latex fonts or predefined symbols using the `"Preamble"` option within MaTeX. I recommend it, it is really easy to use.

Comment: @tortortor Thanks for the feedback. I'll consider adding it to the documentation (blog page).

Comment: Oh, I just realized I was too optimistic. It does respect all the symbols I defined but it also seems to ignore the font. I am using `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`.

Comment: @tortortor [`mathpazo` works fine for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aD8ZP.png)

Comment: This is very nice, but I reeeeaaalllly need to use eps-images in a LaTeX-document. And psfrag-substitutions don't work with my Mathematica eps-files.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why don't you export the result as EPS then?

Comment: @Szabolcs I do that. No problem! But psfrag won't make those substitutions to a 3D-image. And I have [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443431/9446). Something changed in Mathematica from version 9 to version 11, and the change broke this for me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If you are using the MathPSFrag package, then I'm sorry, I can't help you. I never used that package. Maybe you can try MaTeX instead.

Comment: I am under the impression that your MaTeX is designed for using LaTeX inside Mathematica. I need to export images from Mathematica 11.2. in eps-format in such a way that the psfrag commands of LaTeX works as well as it did with Mathematica 9.

Comment: Or, are you suggesting that I should learn to use MaTeX in Matematica 11. And after that I can export the images as eps-files with the LaTeX-substitutions in place. And be guaranteed that the LaTeX-fonts are used? My frustration comes from Wolfram breaking something that used to work well for me. I would need to understand the reason, but this may not be the best place to ask :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen MaTeX is for typesetting labels using LaTeX. People use it to get the typesetting quality of LaTeX even when making figures with Mathematica.  This is also the purpose of psfrag, so for most people MaTeX is a good alternative.  If you just want pretty labels, try MaTeX. If you specifically want to use psfrag for some reason, then I don't have the expertise to help you. If you use MaTeX, then there is no need to run psfrag afterwards. MaTeX does not use psfrag in any way and won't fix any incompatibility between M's EPS export and psfrag.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If you use MaTeX, it will produce labels in the form of graphics (vector graphics), and not the form of font glyphs. This will slightly increase file sizes and will slightly reduce rendering quality on low-resolution screens (i.e. you don't get font hinting and subpixel antialiasing). Most people don't notice this. I mention this as it's the only disadvantage I'm aware of compared to a psfrag-based workflow.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I am still interested in the question as to what changed from version 9 to version 11, and why. But that is off-topic here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's off topic in this comment thread, but it is not off topic on this site, especially if you phrase it as a practical problem: "Here's how I generated an EPS with M9. It worked with psfrag. If I use the same commands with M11.2, the EPS output doesn't work with psfrag. What changed between these versions and how can generate EPS output with M11.2 that's still compatible with psfrag?"

Comment: I tried to do just that [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179208/1155) but didn't get any replies.

Answer (score 67):

A more detailed guide on this topic is included in the [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX/) documentation, in the "Preparing Figures to Size" tutorial.

### Exporting graphics with consistent font sizes

---

I'll show you my preferred way of exporting figures for use with $\LaTeX$.

I prefer to use consistent font sizes in figures.  This means that I need to export PDF figures at the final print size and avoid scaling them within LaTeX. (Note that PDF files contain information about the physical print size of the document.)

---

Let's say we want a 10 cm wide figure that uses 10 point type.  Taking an example figure from the documentation,

```
g = ContourPlot3D[
  x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 + 3 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) == 
   3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 5,
  
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}] (* <-- specify text size in points here *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I increased the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options, otherwise the raggedness of the surface will be noticeable at the high resolutions we will be using here.

I prefer to work in centimetres (and not printer's point, the default unit of Mathematica):

```
cm = 72/2.54;
```

Let's turn on the ruler (`Window -> Show Ruler`) and verify that the following is really 10 cm wide (you may also need to go to `Edit -> Preferences` and set the ruler units to centimetres):

```
Show[g, ImageSize -> 10 cm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you noticed, exporting 3D objects as vector graphics is not ideal, so let's rasterize this figure at the correct size:

```
image = Rasterize[Show[g, ImageSize -> 10 cm], "Image", ImageResolution -> 600];
```

(Unfortunately Mathematica [has trouble with scaling tick marks when rasterizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805451/tick-marks-dont-scale-in-graphics-why-and-how-to-fix-this), so you may want to use an explicit tick specification if this is important.)

A resolution of 600 dpi ensures that it will look excellent in print, but rasterization may take a while.

Finally, export the figure to a PDF of the correct size:

```
Export["figure.pdf", Show[image, ImageSize -> 10 cm]]
```

(When using PDF, it is necessary to specify `ImageSize` within `Show` and not `Export` to avoid some problems.)

You can open the produced PDF, maybe even print it out, and you'll see that all the text is precisely at 10 point size.

---

The same principles can be applied to 2D graphics that export well as vector data:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}]
Export["figure.pdf", Show[g, ImageSize -> 10 cm]]
```

---

Related reading:

- [How to export graphics in “Working” style environment rather than “Printout”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093559/how-to-export-graphics-in-working-style-environment-rather-than-printout) (to ensure that font sizes don't get reduced)
- [Mathematica: Rasters in 3D graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301676/mathematica-rasters-in-3d-graphics)  (how to have rasterized 3D objects with vector axes and ticks?)
- [How to decrease file size of exported plots while keeping labels sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717608/how-to-decrease-file-size-of-exported-plots-while-keeping-labels-sharp)

Comment: While I have been using this workflow for a while, and I am *sure* there have been problems with exporting to size in some previous versions (6 or 7?), I recently realized that this convoluted workflow is not usually necessary in version 8.  I don't have time right now to figure out if a more direct method of  exporting to a given image size and resolution would work fine in all cases, so I am leaving this here as is.  I'll update when I get the time to test.

Answer (score 21):

You *can* use Mathematica-generated PDF graphics in LaTeX, using the `pdflatex` engine. I have been doing this for years. You have several options

1. Use a font such as Times that will embed properly in the PDF, and a LaTeX package that uses matching fonts, such as `mathptmx`, `txfonts` or `tex-gyre` Termes. (There are actually many different font options in LaTeX beyond Computer Modern. If the packages that come with your TeX distribution don't appeal, [I have published some more](http://www.verbeia.com/tex/), including for fonts like New Baskerville.)
2. If you have a Mac, right-click on the graph and choose "Print Graphic" from the pop-up menu, and then "Save as PDF" from the resulting dialog. The PDF that results is a higher version that will embed the Latin Modern fonts. You might need to crop the resulting PDF in Preview before inserting it in your LaTeX file.

PDF format handles opacity properly, so this will also solve some of the other issues you mention.

Comment: I second this. Have done this many times as well. I usually had to play with resizing though - used `convert` under Linux to change image resolution etc (this was a few years ago, M5 - M6. Perhaps now this is unnecessary). +1.

Answer (score 19):

Endorsing Szabolcs' excellent $MaTeX$ package as a way to manage $\LaTeX$ in $Mathematica$ but with an addition that for me at least has removed the significant irritant of having to escape backslashes in strings.

For example, given some previous $\LaTeX$

```
 "\tilde{x}=\begin{cases}
 (\frac{n+1}{2}) \text{th term} & \text{n odd} \\
 ((\frac{n}{2}) \text{th} + (\frac{n}{2}+1) \text{th term})/2  & \text{n even}
 \end{cases}"
```

Applying $MaTeX$ out of the box means having to escape each occuring backslash:

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]

MaTeX@"\\tilde{x}=\\begin{cases}
  (\\frac{n+1}{2}) \\text{th term} & \\text{n odd} \\\\
  ((\\frac{n}{2}) \\text{th} + (\\frac{n}{2}+1) \\text{th term})/2  & \\text{n even}
 \\end{cases}"
```

[image]

It's not just the inconvenience of these mechanical modifications but that this also represents an impediment to programmatically modifying underlying $\LaTeX$. But following [Simon Rochester's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86910/2249) approach (while using a more efficient `StringTake` and specific `MakeExpression` - both as pointed out by Alexey Popkov in the comments), we can directly access the original string. Using `MaTeX` as a wrapper for this interpretative intercept

```
MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"MaTeX", "[", str_String, "]"} | 
    RowBox@{"MaTeX", "@", str_String} | 
    RowBox@{str_String, "//", "MaTeX"} , StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"MaTeX", "[", "StringTake", "[", ToString@InputForm[str], 
     ",", "{", "2", ",", "-2", "}", "]", "]"}, StandardForm];
```

we get a more natural `MaTeX` invocation

```
MaTeX@"\tilde{x}=\begin{cases}
  (\frac{n+1}{2}) \text{th term} & \text{n odd} \\
  ((\frac{n}{2}) \text{th} + (\frac{n}{2}+1) \text{th term})/2  & \text{n even}
 \end{cases}"
```

[image]

Some strings don't expect some of the harmless (in this context) escapes  - e.g. `MaTeX["X \sim \mathcal{N}(1,0)"]` so we'll turn this error message off:  `Off[Syntax::stresc]`

For string pre-processing we can do a similar intercept with a `RawString` wrapper to gain the ability to programmatically generate $\LaTeX$ for subsequent feeding into $MaTEX$

```
MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"RawString", "[", str_String, "]"} | 
    RowBox@{"RawString", "@", str_String} | 
    RowBox@{str_String, "//", "RawString"} , StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"StringTake", "[", ToString@InputForm[str], ",", "{", "2", 
     ",", "-2", "}", "]"
     }, StandardForm];
```

as illustrated by

```
med[var_String] := 
  StringTemplate[RawString["\tilde{`1`}=\begin{cases}
      (\frac{n+1}{2}) \text{th term} & \text{n odd} \\
      ((\frac{n}{2}) \text{th} + (\frac{n}{2}+1) \text{th term})/2  & \text{n even}
     \end{cases}"]][var];

vars = {"x", "y", "z"};

MaTeX[med /@ vars] // Column
```

[image]

Note that `MaTeX` operates on (non-string) expressions in the normal way. Hence programmability is preserved for $Mathematica$ expressions and the frontend's 2D formatting/shortcuts can still be used to readily generate $\LaTeX$ code as desired.

```
mean[var_] := HoldForm[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(var\), \(_\)]\) = \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(var\), \(i\)]\), \(n\)]\)];
MaTeX[mean /@ vars] // Column
```

[image]

[image]

$MaTeX$'s use-cases would seem to be consistency and customising of $\LaTeX$ graphics/formulae, or for presenting complex formulae within a *Mathematica* notebook. Sometimes however, the need may arise for the original *Mathematica* code snippet/function to be included either in a paper or in as part of a collation within a notebook. The obvious method, `HoldForm`, does its holding *after* the underlying boxes have been parsed so to cut the parser off at the pass by way of showing how the code was originally entered, we can define a `RawHoldForm` using this same idiom (I've adapted from Simon Rochester's other [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88634/2249)).

```
MakeExpression[
  RowBox@{"RawHoldForm", "[", expr_, "]"} | 
   RowBox@{"RawHoldForm", "@", expr_} | 
   RowBox@{expr_, "//", "RawHoldForm"}, StandardForm] := 
 HoldComplete[
  ExpressionCell[RawBoxes@expr, "Input", 
   ShowStringCharacters -> True]]
```

and observe the difference

```
HoldForm[((x+"df") // f]

RawHoldForm[((x + "df") // f)]

(* 
   f[x + df]
   ((x+"df") // f)
 *)
```

Putting it all together in a single code block that provides a more natural `MaTeX` invocation, a string pre-processing, `RawString` wrapper and a `RawHoldForm`, the following can be loaded after $MaTeX$ (at least in its current version):

```
Needs["MaTeX`"];

MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"MaTeX", "[", str_String, "]"} | 
    RowBox@{"MaTeX", "@", str_String} | 
    RowBox@{str_String, "//", "MaTeX"} , StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"MaTeX", "[", "StringTake", "[", ToString@InputForm[str], 
     ",", "{", "2", ",", "-2", "}", "]", "]"}, StandardForm];

Off[Syntax::stresc]

MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"RawString", "[", str_String, "]"} | 
    RowBox@{"RawString", "@", str_String} | 
    RowBox@{str_String, "//", "RawString"} , StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"StringTake", "[", ToString@InputForm[str], ",", "{", "2", 
     ",", "-2", "}", "]"
     }, StandardForm];

MakeExpression[
  RowBox@{"RawHoldForm", "[", expr_, "]"} | 
   RowBox@{"RawHoldForm", "@", expr_} | 
   RowBox@{expr_, "//", "RawHoldForm"}, StandardForm] := 
 HoldComplete[
  ExpressionCell[RawBoxes@expr, "Input", 
   ShowStringCharacters -> True]]
```

**Addends**

- While it is the `ToString@InputForm@str` that permits the sought-after programmability, as shown from [MrWizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77184/2249) and [Jen's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76650/2249) answers, the original strings can also be worked with in the frontend for one-off insertions
- The use of `StringTake` avoids the infinite recursion in `MakeExpression`'s definition
- Thus far no downsides have been observed (escapes like \n, \t are not really relevant in latex formatting) although heavier users of $MaTeX$ might notice/uncover issues
- From the originator's comments the original syntax was not designed and hence this would seem to offer an improved syntax for latex formatting in $MaTeX$

Comment: May be instead of modifying `$PreRead` we could make specific definition for `MakeExpression`?

Comment: For example: `MakeExpression[RowBox@{"RawString","[",str_String,"]"},StandardForm]:=MakeExpression[RowBox@{"StringTrim","[",ToString@InputForm@str,",","\"\\\"\"","]"}]`. Now evaluating `RawString["\abc" ]` returns `"\\abc"`.

Comment: er ... yes that might be a little more logical  :) will edit shortly - thanks

Comment: Also I would replace `StringTrim[s, "\""]` with more efficient `StringTake[s, {2, -2}]` which doesn't involve a call to the PCRE library.

Comment: Agreed & Done. Maybe alternatives for the `MakeExpression` can make it more elegant (with no efficiency hits?). I have some stuff do now but feel free to edit the answer for any other improvements etc. Cheers.

Comment: That's very interesting!  I did not think that there was a solution to this problem.  It is a very real usability problem.  Personally, I forget to escape all the time. I know very well I have to, and I respond to support email where people don't do it, but my fingers just refuse to type the double-backslash sometimes.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I've been using $MaTeX$ for a couple of weeks now and similarly noticed fingers being utterly disobedient. My hunch -  it's the subconscious ridiculing the state of affairs - "really ... you have do that; every time ... come on, it's just strings!" I don't really get how `MakeExpression` operates as I seem to have to do too much trial and error too often but this at least seems to do the job.

Thanks for putting together `MaTeX`, it has already come in handy for some teaching materials and re-re-visiting an old paper.

Comment: There's a better way now, thanks to halirutan.  It's still not foolproof, therefore still not included in MaTeX by default. But version 1.7.3 makes it much easier to implement, and [includes a documentation example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zXRQW.png).

Answer (score 14):

I usually draw only the non-textual part in Mathematica export it as PDF (if the graphic is simple) and do all text typesetting in LaTeX to get a consistent use of fonts across the document. This is mainly manual labor. On the LaTeX side I use TikZ. [This entry on TeX.SE might be a starting point.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks)

There is a [solution](http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) for SVGs comming from Inkscape. I have not tried it with Mathematica however.

Regarding the size of the Graphics Objects there is no automatic solution I know of, if you don't want to rasterize the pictures already in Mathematica. In computer graphics you would use back-face culling to remove all the triangles not visible. If you export for example one of the [mathematica spikeys](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spikey.html) into a PDF and open it. The sheer number of triangles exported slows the viewer down so much that you can see the graphic building up slowly. And you can see how many triangles are overpainted. I once tried to reduce the number of triangles however my knowledge about the graphic objects within Mathematica is not good enough for this task. So I usually rasterize them in Mathematica and export them as PNG.

EDIT:
Over at TeX.SE there is a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28021/export-mathematica-8-plot-to-tikz), where tools for an EPS toolchain are mentioned. Never tried them myself however. Gnuplot and LaTeX play well together when EPS is used, perhaps this work for Mathematica EPS too?

EDIT2:
This [entry in Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39974/problem-with-a-very-heavy-eps-image-scatter-plot-too-heavy-as-eps) explains the wrapping of a picture with axis and labels typeset with the TeX fonts in TikZ by an example EPS scatterplot.

Answer (score 13):

About the size of 3d graphics, have you tried the `ImageSize` option in functions like `Plot3D`? For instance,

```
Export["~/Desktop/p2.pdf",
 Rasterize[
  Plot3D[
   Sin[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],
   {x, -Pi, Pi},
   {y, -Pi, Pi}
   ],
  ImageSize -> 1000
  ]
 ]
```

exports a 527KB pdf file here, which looks OK on screen (without rasterizing, you get a 14.4MB file). You can increase the `ImageSize` if this is not enough.

EDIT: Actually, as Szabolcs points out in a comment, for this purpose `ImageResolution` is the right tool:

```
Export["~/Desktop/p2.pdf",
 Rasterize[
  Plot3D[
   Sin[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],
   {x, -Pi, Pi},
   {y, -Pi, Pi}
   ],
  ImageResolution -> 300
  ]
 ]
```

as it takes care of font sizes etc.

Comment: I'd recommend `ImageResolution` instead which makes sure that every element of the image scales proportionally, including text and line widths.

Comment: @Szabolcs you're right, I added it to the answer (if you don't mind). I am making some composite images for a paper and have been using `ImageSize` all the time, so I kept thinking of that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: When I was doing this a lot (2004-2009), I found that both `ImageSize` and `ImageResolution` are useful in combination, since one is not reduced to the other. May be it is different now, I have not checked. +1.

Comment: Here we may observe two of the top experts in this community -- people who have each given crucial help to countless users, answering thousands of questions -- both musing on the possible influence of ImageSize and ImageResolution on the scale and granularity of printed output. Is it not ludicrous that Mathematica should still, after all these years, require undocumented tricks and incantations simply to print something at a definite size? Then to top it off: "May be it is different now." As usual, whoever knows such details is keeping mum.

Answer (score 3):

> That means that I would like to use the same font in the graphics
>   (labels for axis etc) as the main text.

I use MaTeX as follows:

```
    Needs["MaTeX`"];
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amsfonts,latexsym,amsthm,amssymb}",    
           "\\usepackage{pslatex,euler,beramono}"}]; 


funs = {Sin[x], Normal[Sin[x] + O[x]^8]};
Plot[Evaluate[funs], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> MaTeX /@ funs,
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> BlackFrame]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer that I had to find myself:  "MathJax_Main"  font family.  It is automatically becoming MathJax_Math   when you use Italic slant.
Hope it will help.