# How do I cut down on file size of exported eps without losing quality?

Tags: plotting, export

I need to import the following to eps so that I can put it into my TeX file.  The problem is two-fold:  the exported file looks terrible (unlike the Mathematica output), and secondly, the file size is huge (over 1 MB), making it take forever to render in the pdf file.

```
potential1 = 
  Plot3D[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4, {h, -400, 400}, 
    {s, -300, 300}, PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10,  MeshStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.4], Blue}, {Opacity[.2], Blue}}, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
Export["pot1.eps", potential1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

The Mathematica output (in png) is [image].  I can't use png in LaTeX.  I tried to export in pdf, but I'm running into an error: "Cannot determine size of graphic in pot1.pdf (no BoundingBox)."

Comment: I've never had problems with using png in LaTeX. It may be due to my use of [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and pdflatex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you have an older version of $\LaTeX$ installed that doesn't play nicely with `PDF` of `PNG`. So you need to export as `EPS`, encapsulated postscript.

The answer is the same as for this question: [Exporting BarChart3D as PDF produces artefacts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14757/245) - I'll repeat it here because you're asking about `EPS` export, and that question was about `PDF` export:

```
Map[SetOptions[#, 
    Prolog -> {{EdgeForm[], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
       Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> #] &[{{0, 0}, {1, 
          0}, {1, 1}}]}}] &, {Graphics3D, ContourPlot3D, 
   ListContourPlot3D, ListPlot3D, Plot3D, ListSurfacePlot3D, 
   ListVectorPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D, RegionPlot3D, RevolutionPlot3D,
    SphericalPlot3D, VectorPlot3D, BarChart3D}];

potential1 = 
 Plot3D[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 
   0.125 s^4, {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, 
  MeshStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.4], Blue}, {Opacity[.2], Blue}}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
Export["pot1.eps", potential1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

The first cell is there to add a `Prolog` to all your 3D plots that forces the conversion to bitmap upon export. Since this also applies to `EPS`, you'll get a bitmap wrapped in an `EPS` container that can be included in $\LaTeX$. The resulting `EPS` will look just like what you have posted.

Also note that you have to execute the first cell only one time, and all subsequent plots will look fine when exported to `EPS` or `PDF`.