# problem with exporting transparent object to pdf in version 9

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

Here is the code:

```
Export["~/Downloads/1234.pdf", Graphics3D[{Lighter[Black], Opacity[0.5], 
   Polygon@Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x], 0}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}]}]]
```

in version 8, I get

[image]

in version 9, I get

[image]

why the color is different and also there are gridlines in the plot? Is there a way to fix the color and the gridlines in version 9?

Comment: I think you'll find possible answers here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17507/problem-with-transparency-when-i-export-an-eps-file/17515#17515 and here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/copying-an-image-from-the-clipboard-modifying-it-and-returning-it-to-the-clipbo