# Avoiding grid lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

Basically the same question as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps), but now with regions which have opacity.

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Black]];
Export["tmp/region.pdf", %]
```

How do I remove the black lines when exporting to pdf?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? --> http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/644/how-can-all-those-tiny-polygons-generated-by-regionplot-be-joined-into-a-single

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get nice looking `PDF` export in this case is not easy. `Export` is really doing something wrong here. The best option I think would be to do the following:

```
regionplot = 
  RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Black]];

Export["region.pdf", 
 Show[regionplot, 
  Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]
 ]
```

Here, I've tricked *Mathematica* into rasterizing the opaque parts of the plot by  using `Show` to combine the `RegionPlot` with a single invisible textured polygon that triggers the rasterization upon `Export`. To insert this trick, I used a `Prolog` option, but instead you could also use `Epilog`. If you do this often, it would be convenient to define something like

```
rasterTrick[plot_] := 
 Show[plot, 
  Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]

Export["region.pdf", regionplot // rasterTrick]
```

[image: export]

The above is the exported `PDF`.

This is borrowed from my earlier answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14869/245), except that `SetOptions` in this case doesn't work properly as a way to make this trick stick with every `RegionPlot`.

Answer (score 3):

The Adobe PDF generators that are built into various products appear to often be inferior to the results obtained "Printing" with Adobe Acrobat Professional. Using that method, instead of Export, I obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you print directly to PDF (on Mac, you select image, Print Graphic..., then Save as PDF...), you get good results:

[image: print]

So it looks like you can work round the bug in `Export`.

(This is probably the equivalent of [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18630/61), but doesn't involve giving any money to Adobe...)

Comment: My HP Windows came with PDFComplete accessed from Print. But this was only a trial license that has expired. Using File, SaveSelection As.. gives the bad version.