# Little triangles appearing in a Mathematica region plot with "opacity" saved in a PDF file

Tags: pdf-format, plotting

I am trying to produce a region plot of many functions, but *Mathematica* keeps showing me the little triangles when I save it as pdf. I have seen other solutions which fix the problem with PlotStyle-> color, but the problem here is the opacity of each plot.

An example:

```
RegionPlot[{Cos[x^2 y] > 0, Sinc[x y + x y^2] <= 0.3}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 10}]
```

will produce this plot:

[image: I had to take a screen shot of the pdf, because I could not upload the pdf here]

I saw on the internet suggestions such as:

```
g2 = p2 /. {Polygon[__] -> {}}
```

Or some functions that include

```
PlotPoints -> 100
```

But that does not work when you have two functions superposed over each other. Of course, you might suggest that I use `Show` then two region plots, but I don't want to deal with the opacity of each plot, and would rather have *Mathematica* do that for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the answers at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/avoiding-grid-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf

Comment: If you don't want to convert to a rasterized format, then the solution to [Avoiding grid lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2629/245) appears to work fine here. That's why I would consider this a duplicate of the question linked here or in the above comment by @Steve D.

Answer (score 1):

```
Image[RegionPlot[{Cos[x^2 y] > 0, Sinc[x y + x y^2] <= 0.3}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 10}]]
```

Then you can deal with a image object instead of a graphics object

Comment: I intend to use this for a publication, and in the case, when you zoom in, the image is not smooth enough. This won't work, sorry. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Lina Then there is another method. `RegionPlot[{Cos[x^2 y] > 0, Sinc[x y + x y^2] <= 0.3}, {x, -1,  1}, {y, -1, 10}] // FullForm` You can see the structure of the Graphics Object. Delete all `List` with 3 or 4 elements (the triangles and quadrangles), and leave the long List (the curve), then run it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to do that...