# Exporting Texture to pdf with vectorized frame axes

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format, eps-format

If you export Graphics with frame like below

```
Export["R:\\1.pdf", 
 Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0}, {0}, {1}, {1}}], Frame -> True]]
```

Normally, the Frame is correctly vectorized like this

[image]

However, if you export a Texture graphics(no matter you texture what) like below

```
Export["R:\\2.pdf", 
 Graphics[{Texture[""], 
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0}, {0}, {1}, {1}}]}, 
  Frame -> True]]
```

you got

[image]

So wierd! Is there a workaround to make frame of texture graphics exportation vectorized?

Comment: Does this help? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18631/12 (You'll find several other solutions by searching this site, but some may not work in the most recent versions.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Hi, Szabolcs. Glad to see you. Thank you for help. I've been searching this site for hours regarding vectorized frame when exporting pdf. It seems that all solutions are either not working or outdated in MMA 12. I notice that you posted a solution using `rasterizeBackground`. But `Rasterize[Show[...]]` in MMA 12 now returns an `Image` now, so it does give vectorized frame but it has problems either make plot out of frame or the plot range is totally wrong. Can you fix that?

Comment: Where did I post that? Can you give a link?

Comment: @Szabolcs https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/4742

Comment: Please try to add `"Graphics"` as the second argument of `Rasterize` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Szabolcs Great!! It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be great to have that as an answer.