# Export Plot3D in Mathematica 10.1 is Rasterized by default

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d, pdf-format

When I use `Export` to export `Plot3D` to PDF format, I get different behaviour in *Mathematica* 10.1 compared to 10.0. In particular, version 10.1 `Rasterize`s the graphics by default:

```
myFigure = Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
Export["Figure.pdf", myFigure]
```

How can I turn off this rasterization? Can I set the default back to vector images?

Comment: Specify the file format:  `Export["\\Figure.pdf", myFigure, "PDF"]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That doesn't seem to help: the PDF format is implicit from the extension in the file name. If you don't specify it and try to export a 2D plot to PDF, it will be exported as a vector graphic. On the other hand, even if you do specify it, and export a 3D plot, it will be rasterized, at least on my system (v.10.1 Win764bit).

Comment: I am actually surprised to hear that v.10 was exporting the 3D plots as vector graphics though. I don't have v.10 to test with, but I don't recall that being the case: I thought that 3D plots were rasterized upon export no matter what. I'd love to be corrected on this one, as it would be great to have a way to export infinitely resizable 3D graphics.

Comment: I get a rasterized image in both 10.0 and 10.1.  Do you get vector in 10.0?  The doc page on the PDF format mentions the `"AllowRasterization"` option.  Take a look.  Unfortunately in v10.0 and v10.1 it has no effect when I try it.  In v9 it works as described.  Bug maybe?  I would ask WRI support about this.

Comment: I believe that PDF export functionality was rewritten for v10, so they might tell you that this is intentional and the bug is that `"AllowRasterization"` is still in the docs ... let us know what they say, I'm curious!

Comment: @MarcoB I exported LBogaardt's `Plot3D` figure using `Export["\\Figure.pdf", myFigure, "PDF"]` and got a true vector graphics  PDF figure (which, alas, StackExchange will not allow us to load).  [*Mathematica* v. 10.1.0.0 Mac OS X v. 10.7.4 on a Mac Pro]

Comment: I still get a rasterized image using DavidG.Stork's solution. Note there are 3 versions of 10.0, namely 10.0.0, 10.0.1 and 10.0.2. I wonder if this also makes a difference (?). I am using 10.0.0 versus 10.1.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The plot thickens... I am also on v. 10.1.0, but on Win7-64 instead, and I get a rasterized graphic using your method. I would love to find a way to get the vector format instead! This would simplify my life immensely in preparing figures for publication. Thank you for checking though.

Comment: @LBogaardt I tried 10.1.0 and 10.0.2.  Both gave the rasterized version.  I only tried Export, not Save As... .  These two methods sometimes give different results.

Comment: What's the status of this in version 12? None of the tricks suggested here seem to work.

Comment: none of these options work in version 13

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Indeed, 3D plots like this were exported as vector graphics with generally huge numbers of polygons in version 8. But even then, the export was automatically rasterized whenever there were `VertexColors` present in the plot. I described this as a trick for getting smaller `PDF` files [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#PDF3D), and also used it e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14864/245).

So in general, I think it's actually a good thing that `PDF`s generated from 3D graphics are rasterized, provided it's done at a resolution appropriate for the desired device. However, despite this change in version 10, the developers haven't gotten this automatic rasterization quite right yet. For example, [here is an issue that didn't get fixed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58241/245), but which still can be repaired by artificially inserting a texture with `VertexColors` in the plot (that's what I do in my answer to the linked question).

So now we apparently have mandatory rasterization. While this makes exported files smaller, it can also backfire when you just have a `Graphics3D` with simple objects such as lines and a few polygons. Then there may not be any disk space savings at all from rasterization, but you pay the price of lower quality without reaping any rewards.

As a workaround for this lack of choice in `Export`, you could manually **Print** a selected `Graphics3D` as I do in this screen shot:

[image: screen shot]

I right-clicked on the graphic and selected `Print Graphic...` from the context menu. Then I used the print dialog to save as `PDF` instead of printing. The result is a `PDF` file that maintains everything in vector graphics form (at least under Mac OS X). I think the printing route works because it assumes that the proper rasterization is going to be done by the printer driver, so *Mathematica* doesn't have to worry about it (since it's not meant to be a stored file). Of course, they may just have overlooked this loophole (let's hope they keep it open, then one could even consider making a palette for it).

Rasterization can also be avoided by exporting to `EPS`, but that format is outdated and can't handle opacity.

**Edit**

Another way to get the exported file as vector graphics is this:

```
Export["myFig2.pdf", 
 Graphics[Inset[myFigure, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]]
```

Here, I actually export a 2D graphic into which the 3D figure has been placed as an inset.

Comment: If it can be done by menu command, wouldn't you think it could be done by code?  But it may be so well hidden that it's hard to discover how.

Comment: @MichaelE2 This question was the first time I became aware of the change, since I was (and am) using version 8 a lot more than 10. So I haven't been able to find any other programmatic solution... I hope you're right, though. Couldn't find anything in the Advanced Options...

Comment: didn't work for Mathematica10.0.2 on win7

Comment: @Harry Sorry to hear that. Still works fine for me on Mac. Did you try both methods?

Comment: @Jens I now know the problem. I used a .png file for texture in one Sphere[] which may trig rasterize. When I removed png texture it works fine.

Comment: @Harry yes - textures do indeed trigger that. I actually exploited this on purpose to get the opposite of what this Q asks in [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5144/245)...

Comment: @Jens Hi, for the print graphic approach, is there a way to shrink the paper size to be just around the image?

Comment: @user64620 Not automatically, but you can play around with the scale, orientation and paper format in `Printing Settings` in Mathematica's `Edit` menu.

Comment: Anyone know what the status is with Mathematica 11.3?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, on version 10.3 [the solutions proposed by Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/27539) do not seem to work in at least some situations (see edit on [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100156/27539)).

A workaround that I found to work well in my case is simply using `GraphicsRow`, which seems to automatically correctly tweak the options of `Inset` in a way that produces the expected result.
If the 3D graphics to export is `plot`, just use

```
Export["out.pdf", GraphicsRow[{plot}, ImageSize -> 1000]]
```

Another workaround proposed by Alexey Popkov in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100156/how-can-i-export-3d-plots-as-vector-graphics#comment272241_100156) is using

```
Export["out.pdf",Graphics[Inset[plot], ImageSize -> 1000]]
```

These are of course simply slight variations of the solution with `Inset` given by Jens, but they're probably good to know for someone (like me) not knowing how to properly handle the options of `Inset`.

Comment: The key improvement as compared to original [Jens' workaround](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/280) is explicit `ImageSize` specification moved from `Graphics3D` into enclosing `Graphics`. More generally it can be written as `Graphics[Inset[plot], Options[plot, ImageSize]]` and as `GraphicsRow[{plot}, First@Options[plot, ImageSize]]`.

Comment: didn't work for Mathematica10.0.2 on win7