# Mathematica creates a huge eps file

Tags: export, graphics3d, eps-format

I use the following code (based on the responses in my recent relevant questions) in order to generate randomly distributed unidirectional cylinders in a cylinder of elliptical cross section.

```
findPoints = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {low, _Real}, {high, _Real}, {minD, _Real}},
    Block[{data = RandomReal[{low, high}, {1, 2}], k = 1, rv, temp}, 
    While[k < n, rv = RandomReal[{low, high}, 2];
     temp = Transpose[Transpose[data] - rv];
     If[Min[Sqrt[(#.#)] & /@ temp] > minD, data = Join[data, {rv}];
      k++;];];
    data]];

npts = 150;
r = 0.03;
minD = 2.2 r;
low = 0;
high = 1;

ep = With[{a = 2/5, b = 1/2}, 
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
    ParametricRegion[(low + high) {1, 1}/2 + 
      c ({a Cos[t], b Sin[t]} + 
         r Normalize[Cross[D[{a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}, t]]]), {{c, 0, 
       1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}]];

SeedRandom[159];
pts = Select[findPoints[npts, low, high, minD], RegionMember[ep, #] &];
g2d = Graphics[{FaceForm@GrayLevel[0.8], 
    EdgeForm@
     Directive[Thickness[0.004], 
      Black], {GrayLevel[0.6], Disk[#, r]} & /@ pts}, 
   PlotRange -> {{low, high}, {low, high}}, 
   Background -> GrayLevel[0.8]];

mask = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
     MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .02}] &@
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.5}]];
r2d = DiscretizeGraphics[g2d, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
inside = RegionIntersection[r2d, mask];

edge = DiscretizeRegion@*Line@*Intersection @@ 
   Round[{Sort /@ 
      MeshPrimitives[RegionIntersection[r2d, mask], 1][[;; , 1]], 
     Sort /@ MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[r2d, mask], 1][[;; , 
        1]]}, .0001];
points = DiscretizeRegion@*Point@*Intersection @@ 
   Round[{MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[r2d, mask], 0][[;; , 1]], 
     MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[mask, r2d], 0][[;; , 1]]}, .0001];

regionProduct[reg_, join_: True, y1_: 0, y2_: 1] := 
  Module[{n = MeshCellCount[reg, 0]}, 
   MeshRegion[
    Join @@ (ArrayFlatten@{{#[[;; , ;; 1]], #2, #[[;; , 2 ;;]]}} &[
         MeshCoordinates@reg, #] & /@ {y1, y2}), {MeshCells[reg, _], 
     MeshCells[reg, _] /. p : {__Integer} :> p + n, 
     If[join, 
      MeshCells[
        reg, _] /. {(Polygon | Line)[
          p_] :> (Polygon@Join[#, Reverse[#, 2] + n, 2] &@
           Partition[p, 2, 1, 1]), 
        Point[p_] :> Line@{p, p + n}}, ## &[]]}]];
mask3d = regionProduct@mask;
inside3d = regionProduct[inside, False];
edge3d = regionProduct@edge;
points3d = regionProduct@points;

toGC[reg_, dim_] := 
  GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates@reg, MeshCells[reg, dim]];

Graphics3D[{FaceForm@GrayLevel[0.8], toGC[inside3d, 2], EdgeForm[], 
  toGC[edge3d, 2], toGC[points3d, 1], Lighter@Gray, 
  GeometricTransformation[toGC[mask3d, 2], 
   ScalingTransform[0.999 {1, 1, 1}, RegionCentroid@mask3d]]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]

Graphics3D[{FaceForm@GrayLevel[0.8], 
  toGC[regionProduct[RegionBoundary@inside, False], 1], EdgeForm[], 
  toGC[regionProduct@inside, 2], toGC[edge3d, 2], toGC[points3d, 1], 
  Gray, Opacity[0.11], 
  GeometricTransformation[toGC[mask3d, 2], 
   ScalingTransform[0.999 {1, 1, 1} #, RegionCentroid@mask3d] & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, 0.01]]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 100}}]
```

[image]
[image]

Mathematica freezes for five minutes when it is asked to export these two graphics as .eps and produces (the second image for example) a file of 406 Mb.

(Same time behavior for other formats.)

Am I doing something wrong?

Any ideas for workaround? I need this picture for publication.

```
$Version
```

> 10.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)

Comment: Have you seen http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1542/131? Opacity tends to bloat EPS/PDF quite badly. Quick fix: Rasterize at high resolution and export to PNG or similar.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate:-)! No I haven't seen it. Too badly because it is the first link for the list of related ones. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Shall we then close this as a duplicate? Unless your question differs much, I´d suggest so... (PS: I guess you do composites?). Oh, and it might be good to attribute the code from answers you got previously or link these questions/answers.

Comment: Not. I don't think it differs so much. If you wish you can close it as dupicate. I haven't read the whole thread but since the behavior remains still the same after three years this behavior is consireded a feature, buggy or a normal one? It is not clear to me.

Comment: @dimitris This behavior is a feature but starting from version 10 they [changed it for the case of `Export`'ing to PDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87733/280): now `Graphics3D` is rasterized on export to PDF. I would consider this new behavior as a bug but unfortunately is seems to be a design decision.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov thans for the comment.

Comment: Since the behavior remains the same after three years it is not better to leave the question open for a while rather that accept the duplicate nature? Maybe I will receive suggestions or even other workarounds that can be useful for others as well.

Comment: I don't disaggree with the duplicate nature of this question (and I lack fundamental knowledge to support a discussion:-)!). Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @dimitris If someone has new idea on the subject it is better to post it as an answer in the linked thread because the issue is the same. It is better to concentrate relevant answers in one place than have them sprayed over many threads. At the same time your question should not be deleted because it provides additional example of the issue which can be used for testing of the solutions.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Thanks again for the comment. I will make a link to this post.

Comment: FWIW This code itself crashes for me without even trying to export..

Comment: Anyway, I expect the second case to actually work better (smaller file) because the opacity will force rasterization.  In the first case every facet (ie. all the hidden ones) get dumped to the file so it ends up being huge.  We *always* use high resolution rasters for publication anyway..

Comment: I can't recall the size of the first eps. I have to get access to Ubuntu to verify it.