# Exporting or save graph to pdf, when will the rasterization occur?

Tags: plotting, export, image, pdf-format

**For simple graph**

```
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

No matter right click save as pdf or export as pdf, the result is vector image.

**But for `DensityPlot`**

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

I found difference in export and right click save as pdf

Export generate all vector result, while for "save as", the image and axis seems to be vectored, but the ticks is rasterized, this is strange, see below

[image]

**And for 3d plot**

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Both export and right click save as pdf are all rasterized, but it seems that the graph is first rasterized and vectorized

[image]

EPS seems always give vector image.

Finally, save as to pdf is affected by the image resize, for example, we could resize the display graph by dragging the graph border like

[image]

Now if we use right click save as pdf, the pdf is quite small, only 70KB. But `Export` will not affected no matter the size of image.

I also notice that there is an option when saving pdf, but even if I choose vector setting, the pdf is still small 70KB

[image]

Why this vector setting is not giving the same result as `Export`? What is the difference between save as and export? How to save the same result as `Export`?

Comment: For `DensityPlot` "Save Graphic As..." right-click menu item creates a PDF file with raster version of the plot and with no vector elements. You can check this by importing the PDF file backward into the Notebook (for example, by using Drag-and-Drop). I'm using MMa 10.3 on Win7 x64.

Comment: As to why `Plot3D` is rasterized, the answer is in this thread: "[Export Plot3D in Mathematica 10.1 is Rasterized by default](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87733/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov How to confirm `DensityPlot` is rasterized? By eyes?

Comment: For checking you can import the PDF file into *Mathematica* and then use my [`shortInputForm` function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) in order to see what the imported graphics consists of. Alternatively you can open the PDF file in Adobe Acrobat Pro and select the raster image using the "Select" tool.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh, I have acrobat, this is a quick test. Thank you! upvoted

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov So, what about the "pdf option"? why setting it as vector didn't work?

Comment: I recommend you to ask the official tech support about it. I can only say that it looks as an obvious inconsistency and probably should be counted as under-implemented functionality: "PDF Options" does not affect the PDF file produced from `DensityPlot` as well as the `"AllowRasterization" -> False` option does not switch off rasterization in the case of `Plot3D` as discussed in the thread I [linked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87733/280) above.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ok, I understand, Thank you