# Exporting 3D eps figures with transparent background

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d, eps-format

I am attempting to export a 3D plot from mathematica with no background, but I seem to be unable to find a way.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[x], Sin[x], x}, {Sin[x], Cos[x], x}}, {x, 0, 
  1}, PlotLegends -> {a, b}, Background -> None]
Export["test.eps", %, Background -> None]
```

The background of the legend is transparent, but not that behind the figure. I am able to do it in the case of 2D plots.

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Version 10.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With version 10.4.1 I get the plot rasterized (but not the legend) with your code. As a workaround you can use the [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens)' [trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/280):

```
Export["myFig2.eps", Graphics[Inset[pl, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]];
```

Here is how the exported EPS file looks when opened by Adobe Acrobat 11 (I have selected a number on the frame in order to show that it is a selectable text):

[image: scrrenshot]

Not ideal but at least it is in vectors and has no background (the following is a screenshot of a MS Word 2003 document where I imported the EPS figure):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! While it is not ideal, it is a decent work around for now.