# How to insert Graphics3D into Graphics without white frame

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

According to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/38410), the proper way to export 3D graphics as vector graphics is by inserting them into a 2D regular `Graphics` as `Inset`. However, I fail to get rid of a huge white frame around my original image. How can I make this tight? Here are the options that I tried:

```
plot3d = Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Ticks -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
   ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
Framed[
 Graphics[
  Inset[
   Framed[plot3d],
   Automatic, Automatic, ImageScaled[1]
   ],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  ImagePadding -> None,
  ImageMargins -> 0
  ]]
```

[image]

Ideally, I would also automatically choose the size of the "outer" `Graphics` to match the inset object such that no white margins appear and also no cropping occurs.

**Update 2:**

Moved previous update to a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) size for the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) object and the [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) size for the enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object are independently determined. The easiest solution is to give both of them an explicit size:

```
Framed @ Graphics[
    Inset[
        Framed @ Show[plot3d,ImageSize->{360,360}]
    ],
    ImageSize->{360,360}
]
```

[image]

For the example in the comments, my previous answer was not sufficient. For:

```
plot3d = Plot3D[100, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .9},
    BoxRatios -> {3, .9, .5}, ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3},
    ImageSize -> {700, 220}]
```

you can just add `AspectRatio->Full`:

```
Framed@Graphics[Inset[Framed@plot3d], ImageSize -> {700, 220}, AspectRatio->Full]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work well for this example, but why not here: `plot3d = Plot3D[100,
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .9},
  BoxRatios -> {3, .9, .5},
  ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3},
  ImageSize -> {700, 220}
  ]` and `Framed@Graphics[Inset[Framed@plot3d], ImageSize -> {700, 220}]`

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
FrameMargins -> -70
```

or

```
FrameMargins -> {{-80, -80}, {-70, -70}}
```

So:

```
plot3d = Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Ticks -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
Framed[Graphics[
  Inset[Framed[plot3d], Automatic, Automatic, ImageScaled[1]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> 0], 
  FrameMargins -> {{-80, -80}, {-70, -70}}]
```

A humble recommendation to the question poser (and others):  Please use the minimal case for asking a question.  You didn't need to include axes, label axes, include ticks, use image padding, scale the image, set the plot range, and such.  Look how much simpler your code could have been:

```
Framed[
 Graphics[
  Inset[
   Framed[
    Graphics3D[
     Cylinder[]]]]]]
```

or

```
Framed[Graphics[Inset[Framed[Graphics3D[Cylinder[]]]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you David, I will try to do better next time. Is there a way to make your solution work without the frames? I actually used them only to show that there is a lot of wasted space. But then, `FrameMargins` is an option of `Framed`.

Comment: You can use `FrameStyle->None` to hide the `Frame`.