# Inset 3D graphics without cropping

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

This is a follow-up question to [(138886)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138886/how-to-insert-graphics3d-into-graphics-without-white-frame).

According to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/38410), the proper way to export 3D graphics as vector graphics is by inserting them into a 2D regular `Graphics` as `Inset`. Now I want the graphics object and its inset to fit the 3D graphics precisely. The previous question was about a lot of white space that often appears around the object. This question is:

**How can I set the size of the inset to fit the entire 3D graphics without cropping?**

Ideally, a solution would preserve the original 3D graphics size, because things tend to shift and scale disproportionally while rescaling

Here is the example:

```
plot3d = Plot3D[100,
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .9},
  BoxRatios -> {3, .9, .5},
  ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3},
  ImageSize -> {700, 220}
  ]
```

[image]

And here is what I tried:

```
Framed[Graphics[Inset[Framed@plot3d]]]
```

[image]

```
Framed[Graphics[Inset[Framed@plot3d], ImageSize -> {700, 220}]]
```

[image]

```
Framed[Graphics[Inset[Framed@plot3d]], 
 FrameMargins -> {{50, 50}, {-70, -70}}]
```

[image]

```
Framed[Graphics[
  Inset[Framed@plot3d, Automatic, Automatic, ImageScaled[1]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `AspectRatio` of the `Graphics` to be consistent with that of the initial `Graphics3D`, like in:

```
plot3d = Plot3D[100,
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .9},
  BoxRatios -> {3, .9, .5},
  ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3},
  ImageSize -> {700, 220},
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
Framed @ Graphics[{Inset[Framed@plot3d2]}, AspectRatio -> .9/3, 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you!! Do you know why `AspectRatio` is not already defined by setting width and height explicitly with `ImageSize -> {700, 220}`? It seems one really needs both.

Comment: @Felix not really I'm afraid. At first I too tried with only `ImageSize -> {700, 220}` expecting it to work,  but to no avail.