# PDF Export crashes Mathematica

Tags: bugs, front-end, graphics3d, export, crash

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0 and fixed in 11.2.0**

---

The following crashes the Front End when evaluated in version 11.1.0.  Can anyone reproduce it?

**WARNING!** A Front End crash means losing all unsaved notebooks. Proceed with caution!

```
h = PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron"];
g = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.8], EdgeForm[None], h[[1]]}, 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
Export["g.pdf", g, Background -> None]
```

Comment: Adding the Method option seems to make it crash.

Comment: I get the crash with version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64 but no crash with version 11.0.1 on the same machine.

Comment: @M.R.: On lInux (xubuntu x86-64) g is produced, but the graphics cannot be exported to either a PDF or PNG. The program does not crash.

Comment: I get the crash also on Windows 10 (MMA 11.1.0).

Comment: If the crash is in the FE, not the kernel, always put a big warning in your post!  Somebody may not pay attention, evaluate your code, and lose unsaved work.

Comment: Version 11.1 crashes on OS X, version 11.0 doesn't.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry, should have made the warning clearer! I hope you didn't lose any data

Comment: No, this time I didn't (in the past I have). Just wanted to prevent it happening to others :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm still interested in how to export it without the white background

Comment: @Szabolcs what am I doing wrong

Comment: Probably nothing. Have you tried using PNG?  The graphics are rasterized anyway, so there is no point to using PDF.

Comment: Is there no way to get a 2D vector graphic from a 3D?

Comment: @Szabolcs I also tried using ImageGraphics but it looked crappy

Comment: Without `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` I get no crash with version 11.1.0.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/280) workaround also works and allows to obtain vector PDF file: `Export["myFig2.pdf", Graphics[Inset[g, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]]`.

Comment: I would file a report with support so that the issue can be investigated.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I do not get a crash. I do get a crash in export with large data files
Using Linux machine Ubuntu 16.04LTS, ntel® Core™ i5-7600 CPU @ 3.50GHz × 4

Comment: @wlnwtz28, what version of Mathematica are you using?

Answer (score 6):

### Minimal code

Minimal code that reproduces the crash in Mathematica 11.1.1 Windows 7 64 bits

```
Export["g.pdf", Graphics3D[Point[{0, 0, 0}], Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

Where as this will not cause a crash.

```
Export["g.pdf", Graphics3D[Point[{0, 0, 0}], Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}]]
```

### Report

Reported to *Wolfram Technical Support* **[CASE:3938717]** .

**Update 2017-09-11:** Wolfram Technology Engineer confirmed the issue and have passed it along to developers for further diagnosis.

### Workaround

[`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) would prevent the crash

```
Export["g.pdf", Rasterize@ Graphics3D[Point[{0, 0, 0}], Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

### TraceScan

The following [`TraceScan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraceScan.html)

```
TraceScan[
 (PutAppend[#, "TracePrint.txt"]) &,
 Export["g.pdf", 
  Graphics3D[Point[{0, 0, 0}], Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
 ]
```

Comparing `True` and `False` options

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The lines after the first significant differences include

> "MathLink connection was lost."

> `` HoldForm[First]
> HoldForm[LinkError[LinkObject["wq5tk_shm", 3, 1]]]
> HoldForm[LinkError]
> HoldForm[LinkObject["wq5tk_shm", 3, 1]]
> HoldForm[{1, "MathLink connection was lost."}]
> HoldForm[First[{1, "MathLink connection was lost."}]]
> HoldForm[1]
> HoldForm[0]
> HoldForm[1 === 0]
> HoldForm[False]
> HoldForm[False]
> HoldForm[If[False, LinkObject["wq5tk_shm", 3, 1], 
>   Developer`UninstallFrontEnd[]; System`UseFrontEndDump`LaunchFrontEnd[]]]
> HoldForm[Developer`UninstallFrontEnd[]; System`UseFrontEndDump`LaunchFrontEnd[
>    ]]
> HoldForm[CompoundExpression]
> HoldForm[Developer`UninstallFrontEnd[]]
> HoldForm[Developer`UninstallFrontEnd]
> HoldForm[AbortProtect[If[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink] === LinkObject, 
> LinkClose[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink]; 
>      System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink =. ]*
>    If[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$xproc] === ProcessObject, 
>     KillProcess[System`UseFrontEndDump`$xproc]; 
>  DeleteFile /@ Select[{StringJoin["/tmp/.X11-unix/X", 
>      System`UseFrontEndDump`$vncport], StringJoin["/tmp/.X", 
>      System`UseFrontEndDump`$vncport, "-lock"]}, FileExistsQ[#1] & ]; 
>  If[Environment["DISPLAY"] === StringJoin[":", 
>     System`UseFrontEndDump`$vncport], 
>       SetEnvironment["DISPLAY" -> None]; ]; 
>      Clear[System`UseFrontEndDump`$xproc]; ]]]
> HoldForm[AbortProtect]
> HoldForm[If[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink] === LinkObject, 
>    LinkClose[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink]; 
> System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink =. ]*
>   If[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$xproc] === ProcessObject, 
>    KillProcess[System`UseFrontEndDump`$xproc]; 
>     DeleteFile /@ Select[{StringJoin["/tmp/.X11-unix/X", 
>         System`UseFrontEndDump`$vncport], StringJoin["/tmp/.X", 
>     System`UseFrontEndDump`$vncport, "-lock"]}, FileExistsQ[#1] & ]; 
>     If[Environment["DISPLAY"] === StringJoin[":", 
>        System`UseFrontEndDump`$vncport], 
>  SetEnvironment["DISPLAY" -> None]; ]; 
> Clear[System`UseFrontEndDump`$xproc]; ]]
> HoldForm[Times]
> HoldForm[If[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink] === LinkObject, 
>   LinkClose[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink]; 
>    System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink =. ]]
> HoldForm[If]
> HoldForm[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink] === LinkObject]
> HoldForm[SameQ]
> HoldForm[Head[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink]]
> HoldForm[Head]
> HoldForm[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink]
> HoldForm[Symbol]
> HoldForm[LinkObject]
> HoldForm[Symbol === LinkObject]
> HoldForm[False]
> HoldForm[If[False, LinkClose[System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink]; 
>    System`UseFrontEndDump`$felink =. ]] ``

subsequently last lines before crashing.

> `` HoldForm[LinkHost -> ""]
> HoldForm[LinkOptions -> 256]
> HoldForm[LinkProtocol -> Automatic]
> HoldForm[LinkMode -> Launch]
> HoldForm[System`Dump`lcoptions$2519 = Sequence[LinkHost -> "", 
>    LinkOptions -> 256, LinkProtocol -> Automatic, LinkMode -> Launch]]
> HoldForm[LinkHost -> "", LinkOptions -> 256, LinkProtocol -> Automatic, 
>  LinkMode -> Launch]
> HoldForm[LinkOpen["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
> Research\\Mathematica\\11.1\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows-x86-64\
> \\Mathematica.exe /b /min -mathlink -server", System`Dump`lcoptions$2519]]
> HoldForm[LinkOpen]
> HoldForm["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
> Research\\Mathematica\\11.1\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows-x86-64\
> \\Mathematica.exe /b /min -mathlink -server"]
> HoldForm[System`Dump`lcoptions$2519]
> HoldForm[LinkHost -> "", LinkOptions -> 256, LinkProtocol -> Automatic, 
>  LinkMode -> Launch]
> HoldForm[LinkOpen["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
> Research\\Mathematica\\11.1\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows-x86-64\
> \\Mathematica.exe /b /min -mathlink -server", Sequence[LinkHost -> "", 
>    LinkOptions -> 256, LinkProtocol -> Automatic, LinkMode -> Launch]]]
> HoldForm[LinkOpen["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
> Research\\Mathematica\\11.1\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows-x86-64\
> \\Mathematica.exe /b /min -mathlink -server", LinkHost -> "", 
>   LinkOptions -> 256, LinkProtocol -> Automatic, LinkMode -> Launch]] ``

Answer (score 2):

fyi, fixed in 11.2. No crash

---

version 11.1.1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

version 11.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]