# Mathematica 12.1 highly unstable?

Tags: crash, version-12.1

I just "upgraded" to Mathematica 12.1 hoping to address the fact that Export[] would crash the front end Mathematica in 11.3 whenever I would attempt to export a plot to file regardless of file extension (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143831/pdf-export-crashes-mathematica)).

Now Mathematica 12.1 crashes immediately upon opening the front end or attempting to open certain notebooks that worked perfectly fine in 11.3. The strange thing is, that when I run "mathematica.exe" I always obtain a crash, immediately. (I attempted the go-to fix of running the executable as administrator to fix the issue, it does nothing, I run windows 7).

But when I open certain old notebooks that worked perfectly well in 11.3 I either obtain a crash right away, obtain a crash after I am able to look at the notebook for a few seconds, or don't get a crash at all!

What information should I provide to help fix this issue? I am just going to downgrade for now.

Comment: Perhaps. I just downgraded to Mathematica 12.0 and that crash has seemed to be remedied. It seems Matehatica 12.0 has still not addressed the Export issue I mentioned though. I will contact support.

Comment: @Decebalus, first guess...  It sounds like a video card driver issue.  I'd try updating it.

Comment: I am having a similar problem since upgrading to 12.1 on a Mac running OS 10.14.6. The program freezes for no apparent reason - sometimes while scrolling, saving, other simple operations. It hasn't yet crashed during a calculation, so the problem seems to be in the Front End.

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216746/user-interface-mathematica-12-1-terribly-slow Im also on my wy with 12.0 ... again