# Saving 3D plots in PDF crashes Mathematica in Linux

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, crash, linux

I am running Mathematica 12.1 on Fedora 36. When I try to export 3D plots as PDF files, Mathematica crashes. Using the Command Line to get an error log, I am simply reported the title of this post:

`Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.x86.sse41.pblendvb`

I have LLVM version 14.0.5-1.fc36. I also installed LLVM-devel (the dev counterpart) to see if that helped, but nothing changed. [This GitHub post](https://github.com/thewtex/docker-opengl/issues/16) seems to indicate it is a version mismatch, but I am not sure how I could go about fixing that. <s>While [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143831/pdf-export-crashes-mathematica) seems to indicate that opening a ticket is the way to go, I am using a Student licence handled by my university, so I am not sure how I to contact technical support.</s> (Thank you, Domen, for pointing out to me how to send a ticket to technical support!)

To clarify, 2D plots export to PDF with no issue.

---

**EDIT 1**

- A minimal working example that crashes Mathematica: `Graphics3D[Point[{0,0,0}]]`. As pointed out [in this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143831/pdf-export-crashes-mathematica), rasterisation bypasses this issue.
- I have opened a ticket to technical support. I will give timely updates.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Usually, crashes and other user/machine-specific troubles are difficult to be solved on StackExchange, and it is advisable that you contact [Wolfram Technical Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=technical). If you have a legitimate student licence, then you should have your license number or activation key (menu Help > About ...), which you should include in the report for the support.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! Should I delete this thread?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can leave this thread open and update it to include the `bugs` tag along with other details when you hear from support. In order for others to at least recreate the same error, please include a minimal example. Thanks.

Comment: As it stands this question is off-topic, and may be closed. However, to make it useful and avoid closure, you could [edit] the question and offer a *minimum working example* that reproduces the crash, and ask if this can be reproduced in other systems and versions.