# Export 3D vector pdf in Mathematica 13.1

Tags: image

it seems hard to export 3D vector image in Mathematica 13.1, code like

```
fig=Graphics3D[{{Ball[]}}]
Export["3d_ball.pdf",fig,"AllowRasterization"->False]
```

The option "AllowRasterization"->False doesn't work, so if anyone knows how to solve this problem, I want to use vector image in Ai, thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to see if this works for you.  `Export["3d_ball.pdf", Graphics[Inset[fig], ImageSize -> 1000]]`  see [export-plot3d-in-mathematica-10-1-is-rasterized-by-default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87733/export-plot3d-in-mathematica-10-1-is-rasterized-by-default) for reference

Comment: No, it doesn't work orz.

Comment: Speaking from experience: For best quality and least time wasted, just use high-resolution bitmaps (`ImageResolution -> 300` or similar). I know this might not be what you wanted to hear, but this is the best advice that can be give here.

Comment: The FrontEnd's 3D renderer depends on a 3D rasterizer, either your GPU or a software-based one.

Comment: Works in 13.2.0 though some stuff is still pixelated.