# Problem when exporting 3d plots to .EPS

Tags: plotting, eps-format

A journal editor expects high-quality 3D plots (vector files such as .eps, .svg or .pdf) for my article. So, I'm trying to export 3D plots in EPS format.

I know that there are many similar posts on this site. For example; [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117864) [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139948/default-styles-for-exporting-to-pdf-eps-and-svg) [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/how-do-i-cut-down-on-file-size-of-exported-eps-without-losing-quality) [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100312/80263) [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137746/80263) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6301676) etc. So I've been reading the posts and have been applying the suggestions for days.

Yes, I can export the 3d plots as .eps. But unfortunately, they have not high quality or sharpness. They are so blurry.  **I have no choice but to post here.**

I use **Wolfram Mathematica 12.3 on Windows 10.**  (People asking similar questions generally use either Mac OS or previous versions of Mathematica)

**Question 1.** Is the problem originated from the version that is Mathematica 12.3 (or Windows 10)? Which version is ok?

**Question 2.** Shall I use the following mesh grid plot instead of `Plot3D` ? Or which Plot command do you suggest?

For example;

`Plot1=Plot3D[x*Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All,ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]`

or

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]]}
  {xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, .1], Range[-4, 4, .2]];
    c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2];    
    pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, c}, {2, 3}];
    Plot2=ListPlot3D[pts, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
     ImagePadding -> 20, Mesh -> 35, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

Solving the problem is very crucial for me and many Mathematica users.

**Any help or suggestions are appreciated.**

**P.S.** When I export the figure using the following code:
`Export["figure.eps", Plot1, ImageResolution -> 800]`

I get the following results (It is not bad, but it's still blurry.) (Zoom %1200)
[image]
When I export the same plot using Matlab, it gives an excellent .eps image as follows: (Zoom %1200)
**In Mathematica, how to export/print/save like the following high-quality 3D .eps figures?**

[image]

Comment: Don't bother with vector graphics. Use bitmaps and set them to high resolution. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12

Comment: Note: If you export 3D graphics to EPS, it will be bitmap, not vector. EPS can hold a mix of vectors and bitmaps. You can still use `ImageResolution` (and you should do so).

Comment: `Export["figure.eps", Plot1, ImageResolution -> 800]`  is high quality and it is suitable to print.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your interest. I added an exported figure using `Export["figure.eps", Plot1, ImageResolution -> 800]`. But it's still blurry. What is your `SetOptions` ? Maybe it's different from me.

Comment: 2D vector format is not the good format for 3D object since it alway get a large size file. For example `Plot3D[Sin[10 x*y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 80]`  That is why Mathematica doesn't export such vector format no longer.  It is a nightmare when we use Mathematica version 9 or early version.