# Custom named plot themes?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Is there a way for a user to define a custom named plot theme (in V11) and then see it show up as an option?

[image]

Comment: Half is already easy to find, have you tried? [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/5478)

Comment: The other half, i.e. show up in autocompletion: I highly doubt it. Autocompletion uses a separate kernel process and it is not customizable.  [Take a look at the 2015 WTC presentation by John Fultz.](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/presentations/)  He mentions that customizable autocompletion is coming but it doesn't seem to have made it into v11.0.  I was a bit disappointed by that, but I'd rather have a polished, well-implemented feature than something buggy and half done.  So I'm happy to wait knowing that it will come in a future version.