# Assign Plot options

Tags: plotting, options

Is it possible to assign a couple of `Plot` options like e.g.

```
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500
```

to a variable so that I can use it instead of repeating all options in my next plot?

Comment: try `SetOptions[{Plot}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]` see [SetOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html)

Comment: Also `opts = Sequence[Frame->True,PlotRange->All,ImageSize->500 ]` should be possible.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, one should mention that it is possible to define a custom `PlotTheme`:

> [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme)

Second, something like @Henrik Schumacher's suggestion is possible, but (1) you need to use [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) and (2) one can use a simple `List` instead of `Sequence`, which makes combining and adding options somewhat easier.

A couple of examples:

```
myPlotOpts = {Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Evaluate@myPlotOpts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It combines with other options without having to worry about the list structure:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotStyle -> Red, Evaluate@myPlotOpts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]