# Replicating a PlotStyle from Trees, Maps, and Theorems

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time, labeling, style

How might I make a plot with this style, where the callouts are on the side and the y-axes chopped off for a minimal look?

[image]

Here's some example data with the callout that I'd like to add, but I'm not sure how to replicate the style with a `DateListPlot`:

```
ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData["MSFT", "Jan. 1, 2018"]];
callout = {DateObject[{2018, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", 
    "Gregorian", -4.], 96.7699966430664};
DateListPlot[ts, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotStyle->RGBColor[0.979, 0.670, 0.102], 
    Ticks -> {{"Jan 1, 2018", "Mar 1, 2018", "Apr 1, 2018",  "Jun 1, 2018"}}]
```

[image]

This example is from a slide deck of Jean-Luc Doumont which describes his beautifully typeset book, [Trees, Maps, and Theorems](http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/).

Comment: Beautifully typeset as it may be, nevertheless such a graph as the one presented seems very poorly legible to me, and particularly prone to manipulation and misinterpretation, because of the lack of a properly divided vertical axis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[tmtDLP]
tmtDLP[sc_ : 4, nt_ : 5, dtick_ : "Year"][data_, left_List, right_List, 
    opts : OptionsPattern[DateListPlot]] := 
  Module[{dt = Join[{data}, {data[[#]]} & /@ Join[left, right]], joined, ticks,
      marked = Join[left, right], min, max, ymin, ymax, dmin, dmax, jldstyle}, 
    {min, max} = MinMax @ data[[All, 2]];
    {dmin, dmax} = MinMax @ (AbsoluteTime /@ data[[All, 1]]);
    ticks = {#, DateString[#, dtick], {.05, 0.}} & /@ 
        System`DateListPlotDump`getTickDates[dmin, dmax, 2, nt][[-1, 2]];
    {ymin, ymax} = {(sc min - max)/(sc - 1), (sc max - min)/(sc - 1)};
    joined = Prepend[ConstantArray[False, Length@marked], True];
    jldstyle = Sequence[PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
        GridLines -> None, LabelStyle -> 16,  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
        PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
        PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.88, 0.61, 0.14]],
          ## & @@ Join @@ (ConstantArray[Directive[PointSize[Large], #], Length@#2] & @@@ 
            Transpose[{{Red, Blue}, {left, right}}])}, 
        FrameStyle -> {{#, #} &@ Directive[Opacity[0], FontOpacity -> 1], 
          {Directive[Gray, FontColor -> Black], Opacity[0]}}, 
        FrameTicks -> {{data[[Prepend[left, 1], 2]], data[[Append[right, -1], 2]]}, 
          {ticks, None}}, 
        Epilog -> {Gray, Thin, 
            Line[{{data[[#, 1]], ymin}, data[[#]]}] & /@ {1, -1}, 
            Line[{{data[[1, 1]], data[[#, 2]]}, data[[#]]}] & /@ left,    
            Line[{{data[[-1, 1]], data[[#, 2]]}, data[[#]]}] & /@ right}];
    DateListPlot[dt, Joined -> joined, opts, jldstyle]]
```

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[111]
values = 50 + Accumulate@RandomInteger[{-6, 6}, 37];
dates1 = DateRange[{1990, 1}, DatePlus[{1990, 1}, {36, "Month"}], "Month"];
data1 = Thread[{dates1, values}];
dates2 = DateRange[{1990, 1}, DatePlus[{1990, 1}, {36, "Week"}], "Week"];
data2 = Thread[{dates2, values}];

Row[Framed @ tmtDLP[#][data1, {13}, {28}, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {2, 5}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Framed @ tmtDLP[#, 4, "MonthNameShort"][data2, {13}, {28}, 
  ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {2, 5}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Add additional labeled points, override some default options, and add additional `DateListPlot` options:

```
Row[Framed @ tmtDLP[#][data1, {13}, {26, 28}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, BaseStyle ->  PointSize[Large], 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Green, Blue, Orange}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {Top, LightBlue}}] & /@ {2, 5}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Framed @ tmtDLP[#, 4, "MonthNameShort"][data2, {13}, {26, 28}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, BaseStyle ->  PointSize[Large], 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Green, Blue, Orange}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {Top, LightBlue}}] & /@ {2, 5}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Note:** This works as is in Version 11.3 on Wolfram Cloud. For version 9 replace `` System`DateListPlotDump`getTickDates `` with `` Graphics`DateListPlotDump`getTickDates ``, and `Minmax` with `Through[{Min, Max}@#]&`.

Comment: You might be missing an argument, I'm getting an error when I run this. Append::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Append[10,{0.05,0.}]. @kglr

Comment: @M.R. hope the updated version works without issues.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following: (if you don't understand what an option does, leave a comment - *but please look in the documentation center first*)

```
addCallout[min_, max_, date_, val_, Left] := {Line@{{min, val}, {date, val}}, Text[Pane[Round@val, FrameMargins -> 10], {min, val}, {1, 0}]}
addCallout[min_, max_, date_, val_, Right] := {Line@{{max, val}, {date, val}}, Text[Pane[Round@val, FrameMargins -> 10], {max, val}, {-1, 0}]}

ticks = {"Mar 1, 2018", "Apr 1, 2018"}
(* {"Mar 1, 2018", "Apr 1, 2018"} *)

ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData["MSFT", "Jan. 1, 2018"]];
calloutDate = AbsoluteTime@DateObject[{2018, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.];
With[
 {min = Min@ts["Times"], max = Max@ts["Times"]},
 DateListPlot[
  ts,
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal",
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness@Scaled@0.015, CapForm@"Round", JoinForm@"Round", RGBColor[0.979, 0.670, 0.102]],
  Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}},
  PlotRange -> {75, All},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Prolog -> {
    GrayLevel@0.2,
    Line@{{{min, 75}, {min, ts@min}}, {{max, 75}, {max, ts@max}}},
    addCallout[min, max, calloutDate, ts@calloutDate, Left],
    addCallout[min, max, min, ts@min, Left],
    addCallout[min, max, max, ts@max, Right]
    },
  ImagePadding -> 50,
  FrameTicks -> {
    {None, None},
    {
     {AbsoluteTime@DateObject[#, "Instant"], Pane[DateValue[#, "MonthName"], FrameMargins -> 5], {0.02, 0}} & /@
      Join[ticks, {min, max}],
     None
     }
    },
  FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel@0.2],
  BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Segoe UI"]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would it be easy to add multiple callouts from the right as well?

Comment: @M.R. Yes, just add as many `addCallout[min,max,...]` lines as you want. The syntax is `addCallout[min,max,date,value,dir]`, where `dir` is `Left` or `Right`. And `date` should be `AbsoluteTime[...]`

Answer (score 4):

Here is some fairly minimal code that might work for you. It makes use of the augmented form of  `Callout`'s 3rd argument to control the exact placement of the callout.

```
ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData["MSFT", "Jan. 1, 2018"]];
calloutX = 
  AbsoluteTime @
    DateObject[{2018, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.]; 
calloutY = 96.77;

DateListPlot[
  Callout[ts, calloutY, {{calloutX, calloutY + 1}, {0, .5}}],
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.979, 0.670, 0.102],
  Frame -> False,
  Ticks -> 
    {{"Jan 1, 2018", "Mar 1, 2018", "Apr 1, 2018", "Jun 1, 2018"}, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That was sort of my first answer and people had objects. :) Please see [these comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174219/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov. Not the same. You didn't take complete control of the placement of the callout and you didn't get the ticks right.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I meant "sort of". But still, it is not what it is wanted and it is closer what it was argued against.

Comment: @AntonAntonov. What is wanted is not exactly clear. That's why I wrote "might work for you". Personally, I think your first answer and this one are closer to what the OP **needs** than some of others. But that's an opinion.

Answer (score 4):

A completely different approach is to define a custom `PlotTheme` modifying the built-in theme `"Web"` with appropriate options (making use of [this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54637/125)) and use a helper function that constructs the `PlotRange` and `Epilog` options settings:

Use the function `` Themes`AddThemeRules `` to define the new theme `"TM&T"`:

```
Themes`AddThemeRules["TM&T", DateListPlot,
  {AspectRatio -> 1, LabelStyle -> 16, Joined -> True, 
   ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> {{Opacity[0], Opacity[1]}, {Automatic, Opacity[1]}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, 
     {System`DateListPlotDump`getTickDates[#, #2, 2, 5][[-1, 2]] &, None}},
   ## & @@ Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Web", DateListPlot]}];
```

A helper function that constructs the needed lines and labels:

```
ClearAll[addOpts]
addOpts[df_ : "Year", sc_ : 4,  style_ : 16][d_, left_, right_] := 
  Module[{ymin, ymax, min, max}, {min, max} = MinMax[d[[All, 2]]];
    {ymin, ymax} = {(sc min - max)/(sc - 1), (sc max - min)/(sc - 1)};
    {DateTicksFormat -> {df}, PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style[d[[#, 2]], style], 
         Offset[{-5, -1}, {d[[1, 1]], d[[#, 2]]}], Right] & /@ Prepend[left, 1], 
      Text[Style[d[[#, 2]], style], 
         Offset[{5, -1}, {d[[-1, 1]], d[[#, 2]]}], Left] & /@ Prepend[right, -1], 
      Gray, Thin, Line[{{d[[#, 1]], ymin}, d[[#]]}] & /@ {1, -1}, 
      Line[{{d[[1, 1]], d[[#, 2]]}, d[[#]]}] & /@ left, 
      Line[{{d[[-1, 1]], d[[#, 2]]}, d[[#]]}] & /@ right}}];
```

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[111]
values = 50 + Accumulate@RandomInteger[{-6, 6}, 37];
dates1 = DateRange[{1990, 1}, DatePlus[{1990, 1}, {36, "Month"}], "Month"];
data1 = Thread[{dates1, values}];
dates2 = DateRange[{1990, 1}, DatePlus[{1990, 1}, {36, "Week"}], "Week"];
data2 = Thread[{dates2, values}];

 Row[{Framed @ DateListPlot[data1, PlotTheme -> "TM&T", 
    addOpts[][data1, {13}, {28}], ImageSize -> 300], 
  Framed @ DateListPlot[data2, PlotTheme -> "TM&T", 
    addOpts["MonthNameShort"][data2, {13}, {26, 28}], 
    ImageSize -> 300, Filling -> Top, PlotStyle -> 97]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### *May be not so trivial after all*

Looking at the comments and question`s subsequent clarifications this is what I came up with (before giving up going further...):

```
Framed[ColumnForm[{
   Style["MSFT time series", FontWeight -> "Heavy", FontSize -> 14, 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
   Show[{DateListPlot[ts, Filling -> {ts[[1]], ts[[-1]]}, 
      Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> False, 
      PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.979, 0.670, 0.102], 
      ImageSize -> Medium], 
     DateListPlot[{Callout[callout, callout[[2]], 
        Appearance -> "Leader"]}],
     ListPlot[ts["Path"][[{1, -1}]], Filling -> Axis, 
      Frame -> False]}, ImagePadding -> {{40, 40}, {20, 10}}]
   }]]
```

[image]

#### *First answer*

You can just use `Show`:

```
Show[{
 DateListPlot[ts, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.979, 0.670, 0.102]], 
 DateListPlot[{Callout[callout, callout[[2]], Appearance -> "Leader"]}]
}]
```

[image]

Also, see examples in [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html).

Comment: that doesn’t look visually at all like what the OP wants (clipped frame, horizontal callout, etc...)

Comment: @user56601 You commented 1 min after I submitted my answer. Also, see my update -- OP desired form can be done with `Show`, `DateListPlot`, and `Callout`. Also, I think the question is trivial, so I voted to be closed.

Comment: Did you figure out how to clip the frame?

Comment: @user5601 "Did you figure out how to clip the frame?" -- I am not sure what that means. Can you be more clear? (So, I can figure it out for you...)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I've added a better image to my question showing the two stylistic features of the plot I'd like to capture

Comment: @M.R. Ok, thanks. I did not realize question's strong emphasis on the stylistic form reproduction. (And I retracted my "to close" vote.)