# Plotting: Change colour scheme and line thickness at the same time

Tags: plotting, style

Some stylistic attributes of plots are independent of colour, e.g. thickness, dashing, etc.

I can make the lines thick in this plot without having to specify a separate style for each line:

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image]

I can also easily change the colour scheme:

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> 98]
```

[image]

How can I change both the colour scheme and the line thickness (or dashing) at the same time, without having to specify a separate style for each plotted function?

The following works, but it is cumbersome and requires hard-coding the number of plotted functions (or putting in an arbitrary large number):

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[ColorData[98][#], Thickness[0.01]] & /@ Range[4])]
```

[image]

I know that I can do `PlotStyle -> 98, PlotTheme -> "ThickLines"`, but that requires me to use a single pre-defined line thickness (or to choose from only a few). It does not allow me to set my own custom base plotting style with an arbitrary thickness and dashing specification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the (undocumented) `Method` suboption `"DefaultPlotStyle"` as a second place to specify plot styles:

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> 98,
 Method -> "DefaultPlotStyle" -> Thick
 ]
```

[image]

More generally, you could specify a list of directives in `PlotStyle`, and a common default in `"DefaultPlotStyle"`:

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Green, Blue, 
   Directive[Orange, DotDashed]}, 
 Method -> "DefaultPlotStyle" -> Thick,
 BaseStyle -> Dotted
 ]
```

[image]

Note however that this can interfere with `PlotTheme`, since themes use the same option to set common default styles. In case more control is needed, you can register a custom plot theme that sets the `"DefaultColor"`, `"DefaultThickness"`, etc. suboptions before they are merged into `"DefaultPlotStyle"` by `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme ``:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[{"CustomTheme", 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]}, s_] := Themes`SetWeight[
  {opts},
  Themes`$DesignWeight
  ]
```

This defines a new `PlotTheme` that accepts an arbitrary lists of options to be added to the plot theme options (see e.g. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111439/36508) for more details on the mechanism). It can be used for example like this:

```
Plot[TriangleWave[x], {x, 0, 3},
 PlotTheme -> {
   "CustomTheme",
   "DefaultColor" -> Red,
   "DefaultCurveStyle" -> JoinForm@"Round"
   }]
```

[image]

While you can in principle set any option with this "theme", the following are particularly interesting: `"DefaultColor"`, `"DefaultThickness"`, `"DefaultTransparency"`, `"DefaultDashing"`, `"DefaultCurveStyle"`. This is because these particular options are combined into `"DefaultPlotTheme"` as part of `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme ``, as mentioned above, which reduces interference between these custom settings and other themes (including the default one) as much as possible.

Comment: What does the `98` in `PlotStyle -> 98` mean? Are such numeric values for `PlotStyle` documented somewhere?

Comment: @murray The 98 refers to the indexed colour schemes. `ColorData[98]` should provide the same result. You can see the numbers for the colour schemes if you go into the "Palettes" menu > "Color Schemes". If you look at the "Indexed" palette, there are numbers associated with each one.

Comment: @murray 97 is the current default. The ones started at 97 were added in version 10.0 and I find them much more usable (distinguishable) than the earlier ones.

Comment: @Lukas Thanks for pointing out the interference with the plot theme. It even interferes with the default style (e.g. it resets the thickness). But it is still very useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it resets the thickness"? Isn't the changed thickness the intended result?

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, this example I wanted to change the thickness. But in general, I want to set a base style in addition to specific styles set with `PlotStyle`. Consider this: `Plot[TriangleWave[x], {x, 0, 3}, 
 Method -> "DefaultPlotStyle" -> JoinForm["Round"]]`. Just setting the `JoinForm` affects the default thickness and the default colour as well. No big deal, I was just a bit surprised.

Comment: @Szabolcs Now I see what you meant, thanks for clarifying. I have updated the answer with an example implementation of the custom theme that I have mentioned in my previous answer. The new solution should not suffer from any "interference" issues.