# What's the best way of setting global defaults for my Plots?

Tags: plotting, style, plot-themes

Obviously there are many ways to change the global settings, such as `$PlotTheme` or `SetOptions[]`, but what I'm looking for is a way to streamline the process of setting the right options for all the plots in my notebook - especially referring to things like font size, tick size, etc.

Is there a way for me to set these options for every plot in the notebook? Maybe even a way to change the default settings for plots? I have to create a lot of plots with Mathematica, and I would love there to be a quick way to have them all abide by the same standards.

Comment: If you put a `SetOptions` statement in your Init file it should have the same effect as changing some of the default options in your plots.

Comment: I think you might also find this interesting: [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/27951)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of a group of custom plot settings that you can define once at the top of a notebook, and can use repeatedly after that:

```
myPlotSettings1 = { 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.01]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.01], 
      Dashing[0.02]}, {Black, Thickness[0.01], Dashing[0.01]}, {Green,
       Thickness[0.01]}},
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
   Axes -> True,
   Ticks -> Automatic,
   GridLines -> Full,
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14},
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black],
   ImageSize -> 500};
```

Here is how you use your custom plot settings inside a Plot command:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], None, Sin[x]/x}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
Evaluate[myPlotSettings1],
PlotLabel -> "Plot Title",
FrameLabel -> {"X Axis Label", "Y Axis Label"}]
```

[image]