# Why are my images not printing at the expected size?

Tags: graphics, printing

I [understand how](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5442/37) (in theory) to get images to be a specific size in inches, but when I [follow the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html), all of my output seems to be scaled down by a factor of a bit less than 70% (e.g., `ImageSize -> 72x8` gives an image size of about 5.5 inches rather than 8).

How do I ensure that my images print at a specified size in inches? Are there settings or additional options beyond those described in the documentation for `ImageSize` that I need to use?

---

In context, what I'm trying to do is print a generated graphic from within a Manipulate using a button using

```
Button["Print",  NotebookPrint[pat]]
```

or perhaps something like

```
Button["Print", NotebookPrint[Show[pat, ImageSize -> 72 patzise]]]
```

and I'd ideally like to apply whatever settings are needed to get a properly sized output, without messing with global or notebook level settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the printing environment on 'Working' using the `File > Printing Settings > Printing Environment` menu. The default for printing, the *Printout* stylesheet uses a condensed version of the screen stylesheet.

Proof:

If you open the stylesheet editor (`Format > Edit Stylesheet...`) while using the standard notebook style you get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Click on Default.nb and open the environment style to find the Printout style:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Open the Printout cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to find:

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], Magnification -> 0.72]
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124065/590388

Comment: That works in some cases (e.g. using the context menu) but not others, in particular not for `NotebookPrint[g]`, which is what I'm doing. I've tried `Button["Print", {SetOptions[pat, 
   PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"], NotebookPrint[pat]}]` (I need to use a button to print), but that doesn't work.

Comment: So what I need to do in context is set just the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` for the expression I'm printing (as in the comment above), as I print, but ideally leave global settings unchanged.

Comment: I've updated the question to that effect.