# Mathematica 11 with High DPI 4k screen

Tags: front-end, system, scaling

My laptop has a 17 inch 4k screen, running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 1604. Both systems are set to 2x scaling. But Mathematica 11 (released 2016-08-08) is still blurry like version 10. Is there a simple fix to this problem?

Comment: I do not believe Mathematica on Windows/Linux supports High DPI screens as of this point in time.

Comment: Related: [120463](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120463/5478), [Fontsize is too small](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/745/5478), [What is a printer's point?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109813/5478), [121089](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121089/5478)

Comment: @user6014 Is 4k supported on a Mac?

Comment: @QuantumDot I know retina displays are supported, yes

Comment: @Kuba The fontsize is not small, they are just blurry.

Comment: What a pity that they have this on Mac but still not on Windows.

Comment: Mathematica 11.2 has supported HiDPI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best thing to do, IME, is to set the default notebook zoom level to something higher. This way, the text is rendered crisply and at a reasonable size.

You can do that as follows:

1. Go to `Preferences` -> `Advanced` -> `Open Option Inspector`
2. Set `Show option values` to `Global Preferences`
3. Go to `Notebook Options`
4. Go to `Display Options`
5. Change magnification to whatever works for you.

Now, "100%" (default mag) will be rendered at whatever magnification you chose here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the resolution issue or am I missing something? I have my Windows setup at high DPI too and this doesn't alter the crispness of the resulting display.

Comment: @MohammedAlQuraishi Disable "DPI scaling" for Mathematica, then do what is suggested, which effectively boils down to `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Magnification -> 1]`. A lot of things will not look quite right after this though (e.g. the search box in documentation), but better than nothing.

Comment: On 4K, I recommend `Magification -> 3` at least.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the Welcome screen and file names in the initial window are not scaled and are unreadable. Only once I open a Notebook I can read the text properly.

Comment: Also if you use method in the answer, then do this (but be aware that, notebook will look fine but everything other will be small):
1. Leftclick Mathematica shortcut.
2. Compability.
3. Change high DPI settings.
4. High DPI scalling override.
5. Set dropdown box to "Application".

Comment: I'm on Mathematica 12 and unfortunately this doesn't make any difference for me.

Answer (score 9):

Mathematica 11.2 seems to use Qt 5.6 framework which supports [DPI scaling override](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html). At least on Linux, it's possible to get bearable results by starting Mathematica as follows:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5 Mathematica
```

`QT_SCALE_FACTOR` is an environment variable that defines UI scaling. It seems to work quite well except for the splash screen.

Comment: Does this work in Windows as well?

Comment: You could try setting an environment variable either from CMD prompt or globally (remember to remove it later as it may break other QT apps)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. I have a hunch that Mathematica does not use the QT framework on Windows. Oh well, with the disaster that is Windows 10 I may be switching to Mac OS soon anyway (Macbook Pro is on order). Then I hear that the Mac frontend is still 32-bit, with accompanying limitations. Can't win. Unless I switch to Linux...

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to use one toolkit on Linux and another on Windows. You can check the program directory to see if there are files like QtCore5.dll. I have tried to run another Qt app in Windows and it worked for me this way: `C:\Users\User>set QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2` \\
`C:\Users\User>"C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedCrunch\speedcrunch.exe"`

Comment: There are no Qt libraries for Mathematica on Windows, and no acceptable high-DPI behavior can be achieved in Windows. Mathematica is near-unusable under high-DPI Windows scenarios.

Comment: That's so weird. I'll check it when I have a chance. Maybe it just uses older Qt version and it's statically linked.

Comment: This makes dialog boxes gigantic, although the rest of Mathematica is okay.

Answer (score 6):

With Windows 10 Build 15002 and above, you can use the following settings to obtain a higher resolution of MMA than magnification for 200%, for example.
[image: Setting]

Comment: This makes Mathematica readable, but the fonts are still blurry and not as crisp as they should be on such a high-resolution screen (see here http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1202244)

Comment: Two figures/screenshots before & after the ticking are appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Linux?

Answer (score 6):

After a long wait, finally, Mathematica 12.1, [launched in March 2020](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html), introduces full support for high DPI monitors for both Windows and Linux. The upgrade from previous versions of Mathematica is beautifully impressive on a high-DPI screen!

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add up to the answer by [divenex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/41148/divenex).

Indeed, [since version 12.1](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) Mathematica can perform a proper Hi-DPI scaling. I tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the result was satisfying everywhere, except the initial splashscreen that is still somewhat broken. Both the UI elements and notebook contents, including code suggestions, scale correctly.

**One non-trivial trick I wanted to mention**, that could save someone's time:

In order to achieve proper scaling, one should navigate to `Format → Object Inspector → Global Preferences → Global Options → System Configuration` and set `ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode → False`. Then inside the field `ScreenInformation` in the same panel, one should set `Resolution→xxx`, where `xxx` can be obtained by running `xdpyinfo | grep resolution` in Ubuntu.

Quick demonstration. Before:

[image: Scaling before]

And after the aforementioned modification:

[image: Scaling after]