# Mathematica 12 blurry with High DPI 4k screen

Tags: system, scaling, format

Same as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123717/mathematica-11-with-high-dpi-4k-screen). Everything very blurry. Maybe there is any new solution for Mathematica 12 under Windows 10?

Comment: Don't know why this is being downvoted.  That question was asked over three years ago, and it seems reasonable to think that Wolfram may have improved it since then

Comment: @MaxCoplan My understanding was that if an updated answer to an old question is desired, you should just add a bounty.

Comment: It was [promised](https://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2019/04/version-12-launches-today-big-jump-for-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) to be solved by "our next release, in 12.1" (see comment area). Have to wait a couple of months.

Comment: @wdscxsj from your link: "High-dpi support for Windows is coming in our next release, in 12.1." Great news!

Comment: @vasili111 Dive down into the comment area of that link and you'll see it's 12.1. And by "a couple months" I mean, according to the recent release history, it usually took 200+ days to move from version X.0 to X.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blurred frontend text in Mathematica 10, Windows, High-DPI Display](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58119/blurred-frontend-text-in-mathematica-10-windows-high-dpi-display)

Comment: @Szabolcs While it is good to have that link here, I think that reasking that question again is quite reasonable if we take in the account the when linked question was asked. I do not see the reason why question was put on hold.

Comment: The release of 12.1 in the next few months [after Nov 1, 2019] will include ... higher DPIs for Windows. [[ref](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/11/01/wolfram-technology-conference-2019-its-a-wrap/)]