# Broken Image Assistant Toolbar formatting

Tags: front-end, customization

One of the, hmm, "pleasures" of Mathematica is the appearance of those half-broken UI elements, that are hardcoded in some inappropriate way or another. Another example I just came across is the Image Assistant Toolbar. Here is what it looks like for me:

[image]

It turns out that the StyleSheet that's in use does have *some* effect on how much of that "more..." text fits into its button, but even if I use the default StyleSheet it doesn't fit, on my particular Windows 7 x64 machine. I'm sure there's some Windows machines where this works, but none of mine fall in this class. My guess is that OS settings affect the display of this as well, in possibly mysterious ways. Does anyone know how that toolbar is coded? Is there a notebook that I could edit so this looks the way it's supposed to?

---

After trying Karsten's suggestion in his answer (which solved the issue in the original image I posted), I checked the other tabs of that bar, and found this:

[image]

Overall, font sizes in this interface are a complete and hopeless mess. See this:

[image]

and notice the font size for the "other" label at the bottom. Well, I am sure that Karsten may be able to help me ultimately fix this one too, but I am certain that I'll find similar issues with pretty much every single new toolbar that I may discover. One may ask why Mathematica users have to redesign their user interface themselves if they want it to be rendered correctly.

Comment: No, I did not modify the Default.nb StyleSheet.

Answer (score 3):

### Edit:

The reason, why your UI elements appear to be broken, is, that the font is enlarged due to your customization of `FontProperties`. You can make this UI use the correct `FontProperties` by adding the default as an option to its `Cell`:

```
Export[
 FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}],
 Insert[
  Import@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
     "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}],
  FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 72},
  {1, 1, -1}
  ]
 ]
```

---

### Original Answer:

Before changing the underlying file you can use, e.g.,

```
CellPrint@First[
  Import@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
      "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}] /. 
 {(BaseStyle -> {"TextStyling"}) -> (BaseStyle -> {"TextStyling", FontSize -> 10})}]
```

to check, if changing the `FontSize` resolves that issue for you.

When you found the setting that works for you, you can save it to your `$UserBaseDirectory` instead of modifying the original file. For example via

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}], 
 Import@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}] /. 
 {(BaseStyle -> {"TextStyling"}) -> (BaseStyle -> {"TextStyling", FontSize -> 9})}
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, I use my own StyleSheet for my new notebooks anyway. I tried the code you gave, and to me it looks like if I put a `FontSize->13` in there, the result looks like what I get with Default.nb. If I want the text to fit in the button, I need to set `FontSize->12` if I use Default.nb, but I need to set  `FontSize->9` if I use my own StyleSheet (which has the ScreenResolution property set to the correct value of 96DPI rather than the incorrect value of 72DPI Mma on Windows uses by default). So, what do I need to do to fix this issue using my StyleSheet?

Comment: Of course, I don't want to change font sizes of already existing styles in my StyleSheet.

Comment: 7: This kind of works, but see my answer (so that I can post another image). No `Magnification` never solves anything, in my opinion, because of the different effects it may have on different types of notebook cells.

Comment: On the Magnification versus ScreenResolution topic, also see my response [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120463/magnification-screenresolution-screeninformation-and-printing-please-shine-so/120654#120654).

Comment: No, while my changing the Font Properties makes things worse, the dialog boxes are broken even with the standard Default style sheet. My guess is this is related to Mathematica relying on people using a standard set of fonts, at the standard sizes, in Windows. The solution would have to be button sizes, frame sizes, etc., that can adjust to accommodate the font sizes that are being used. Or, to specify the fonts to be used for these interfaces independently. You know, the way hundreds of thousands of other Windows applications do it...