# ImageSize as absolute (metric) value

Tags: graphics, export

I have wondered more and more often lately how the size of an image is handled when displayed or exported. The documentation implies that the via  `ImageSize` the size could be set in printer points (per inch). That does however not correspond with the displayed graphics (for instance `ImageSize-> {72 1, 72 1 }`) does not render a generic plot with the expected size of one inch square. (UI magnification at 100%)

I am using Mathematica 9 on OS X 10.9 and usually use .eps for exporting plots (since .pdf export doesn't really work that well with fonts and all)

Comment: This is `Export`-related only (but duplicate-ish): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5442/131. I guess sizes on-screen are another animal entirely.

Comment: `ImageSize` only changes the display. To actually change the size of the image in pixels (for instance when you export), use `ImageResize`. Then you can specify exactly how big/small you want it.

Comment: For exporting to PDF, I sometimes need to use the workaround `cm = 72/2.54; Export["file.pdf", Show[graphics, ImageSize -> 10 cm]]`.  This gives a size of precisely 10 cm.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12), some of the ideas may be of use to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I export graphics like this:

```
cm = 72/2.54;
Export["file.pdf", Show[graphics, ImageSize -> 10 cm]]
```

For some reason `Show` is required when exporting to PDF, i.e. you can't just use the `ImageSize` option directly in `Export` and still get the expected result.

---

Regarding display on the screen, `ImageSize` is interpreted as pixels for on-screen display and as PostScript points (1/72 inch) for exporting to printable formats such as PDF.  In other words, Mathematica always assumes the display to be a 72 ppi one.

Comment: N.B. `ImageSize` is (documented to be) printer's points whether onscreen or on paper. It just happens that many screens have (or used to have) 72 pixels per inch, and *Mathematica* [uses this as a default](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/748/) instead of the actual resolution, as you noted in your answer in the link. Why it does this, I don't quite know.

Comment: @OleksandrR. and Szabolcs, If I understand correctly that means for MMA  pp == px is always True? And this is quite fundamental and not mentioned in documentation, right? p.s. There is `m` `cm` naming problem.

Comment: @Kuba what does `pp == px` mean?

Comment: @OleksandrR. printer's points, pixels.

Comment: and by always I meant by default. :P

Comment: @Kuba I don't know whether the default may change in future, but it does know what the actual screen resolution is even though it doesn't use it. See `"ScreenInformation" /. SystemInformation["Devices"]` vs. `Options[$FrontEndSession, FontProperties]`

Comment: @OleksandrR. But not mentioning this in `ImageSize` documentation is a serious thing (for those who care about style a lot). P.s. I put `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 96}]` and I expect `Pane/@{ RandomImage[1, {100, 100}], 
RandomImage[1, {100, 100}, ImageSize -> {100, 100}]}` to have different sizes in the screen, they don't am I missing something?

Comment: @Kuba I agree that this doesn't seem right. Sometimes an assumption of 72 dpi is hard-coded and `ImageSize` uses that assumption; other times there is the `ImageResolution` option as well. It seems that `ImageSize` is always supposed to be printer's points, though, even if the front end doesn't know how many pixels that corresponds to. `RasterSize` is explicitly pixels.

Comment: @Kuba When exporting graphics, it's true (with default settings) that pp = px.  But I am not certain about exporting other notebook objects, such as `Row`, `Column` or `Legended` (!!!).  I think Mma was using the "Printout" environment for notebook objects which has a smaller-than-one scaling factor by default.  I don't remember the details, but I know Alexey Popkov had either a question or answer (or both?) on this topic (shrinkage with Printout environment).

Comment: @Kuba The `ImageResolution` option can change this `72`. It has to be used in `Rasterize` or `Export`.  Another thing: do not use `ImageSize` in `Export`, use it instead as a `Graphics` option to get the desired result. `Export[..., g, ImageSize -> ..., ImageResolution -> ...]` is bad.  `Export[..., Show[g, ImageSize -> ...], ImageResolution -> ...]` is good.  At least for bitmap formats like PNG.  But I don't understand why!

Comment: @OleksandrR. That's ridiculous... Szabolcs, I see, well I'm more concerned about displaying in notebook than about exporting at the moment.

Comment: @Kuba There's also an in-notebook ruler: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12