# How to adjust the correct ImageSize between two plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, data

Let's consider the following simple plot

```
P0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotLabel -> 
     Style["Test 1", FontSize -> 20, Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
     AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550];
```

The second one is much more complicated ad we need to create some data in order to replicate the situation

```
n = 5000;
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[{10^-2, 10^4}], 
RandomInteger[{0, 2}]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

Define a color function

```
valrange = {-2, 4};
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 3]]], valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := If[x[[4]] == 0, Gray, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]];
```

Create a colrbar

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, "test"}, {None, None}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

A simple contour

```
C0 = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Contours -> {0.5},
     ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.005]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     ContourShading -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
```

and finally the modified density plot

```
With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 550}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
    Row[{Show[
     ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
     PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.005], colfunc[#, cf]} & /@ data), 
     AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, 
     Axes -> None, FrameTicks -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
     ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}, opts, 
     PlotLabel -> Style["Test 2", FontSize -> 20, Black, 
     FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], C0, PlotRange -> 0.9, 
     PlotRangeClipping -> True], 
     Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
     ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 40}}, opts]}]]
```

There are two issues regarding this second complicated plot:

(a). For large data sets, (`n` > 10000) the programs needs more than 10 minutes so as to create the plot! Is there any way to speed up the process?

(b). Even though I set `PlotRange -> 0.9, PlotRangeClipping -> True`, we see that the frame in all directions does not end at exactly 0.9 but in 0.9 + dx. Why?

Now, if we put together the two plot

[image: plot]

it becomes evident that size of them do not match. For both plots I used `ImageSize -> 550` but it seems that the second one (the complicated) is smaller. I suspect, that this has to so with the colorbar it carries together. So, my question is: how can I get the second plot match in size with the first?

**EDIT**

Apparently, each (x,y) point should be treated as a separate list by using `List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]]`. That's the reason why the code is very slow when we have many points. Unfortunately and strangely enough I cannot use `ListDensityPlot` simply because stupidly it joins by default the points without giving you an option for that!

Comment: [no problems here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/84u1U.png) - the top of the "Test" text aligns with the top of the left plot.

Comment: @cormullion See my update. They actually do not align. I would like the square frame of the second plot has the same size as the first one and also the titles to align each other.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z concerning (a) I think you should replace in your plotting function List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]] with simple data[[All, {1, 2}]]

Comment: @tchronis It works way much faster! Thanks. What about the other issues?

Comment: @tchronis Well, in fact this may my faster but it meshes up with the colors. It should be `List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]] `

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I understand your point about a) but handling each point separately with a matching color leads to this delay - probably you should collect first the points of the same color and then ListPlot them. About b) you are correct ImageSize is an option that specifies the overall size of an image to display for an object. I am searching for a way to fix your plot's area image size...

Comment: To prevent padding the plot range, use `PlotRangePadding -> 0`

Comment: As for the size, you have set `P0` to have a *width* of 550 pixels, and the complex plot to have a *height* of 550 pixels, with lots of image padding. If you want the frames to line up use the same settings for `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` in `P0` as you do in the complex plot.

Comment: @SimonWoods Perhaps you should include all these in an answer so as to vote for it.

Comment: @tchronis "collect first the points of the same color and then ListPlot them" how can I do this?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z even if you specify the required width through ImageSize on screen you will get a relatively close size (in pixels). You can try copy as graphic and paste to an imaging software to see the differences. I copy a link here that may help you further. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/imagesize-as-absolute-metric-value

Answer (score 1):

About a) :

I noticed that the output of your `colfunc` produces symbolic expressions that certainly slow down evaluation. This is caused by Log10.

Try `colfunc[#, "Rainbow"] & /@ data` to check it out.

So try to change to `data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 3]]] // N, valrange];`

Adding `//N` speeds up `colfunc` by a factor of x7.

Also changing `colfunc[#, cf]} & /@ data` to `colfunc[#, cf]} & /@ 1.data` you will gain another 2x.

With these changes in my machine it took 10 seconds to plot for n=10000.

I also noticed that your routines are memory consuming so you could try to use packed arrays also.

Pasting changed code :

```
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 3]]] // N, valrange];


With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 550}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
 Row[{Show[
    ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
     PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.005], colfunc[#, cf]} & /@ 1. data), 
     AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, 
     Axes -> None, FrameTicks -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
     ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}, opts, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style["Test 2", FontSize -> 20, Black, 
       FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], C0, PlotRange -> 0.9, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True], 
   Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 40}}, opts]}]]
```

Comment: I' m getting some errors now! Just to be sure what we are changing please, post the complete part of the code `With[ ... ]`

Comment: In my machine (Win XP, Mathematica, v9.0.0, Dual Core 2.2GHz) `n = 10000` took about 30 sec. My real data files have at least 50000 points.

Comment: In my machine (WIN7, Mathematica, v9.0.0 clock at 3Ghz  , for `n=50000` it took 510 sec. I am testing with PackedArrays , hold on...

Comment: Check also this link : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar

Comment: For `n=50000` my machine needs 735 sec. Surely it must be a way to speed up the process.