# How to specify units for ImageSize Option?

Tags: plotting, graphics, cdf-format, units, printing

I'm trying out making a CDF and I want it to print within the margins of Letter paper. There is an `ImageSize` option that I would like to set; some plots will be in a grid, some alone.  I thought using `Quantity` would be good for this since I know the width of the paper. I tried:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> {Quantity[4, "Inches"], Automatic}]
```

This gives an error:

```
The specified setting for the option Graphics3DBoxOptions, ImageSize cannot be used.
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? How do I set the image size in units?  What are the units of `ImageSize`? Can I use `UnitConvert` on `Quantity` to get to the `ImageSize` units?  I'm using Mma 10.

Thanks,

Edmund

Comment: Possible duplicates?: [(5442)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5442), [(37345)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37345)

Comment: It would be nice, though, if the `Unit`-based answers were also given there.

Comment: @MichaelE2 If this is closed and if it is agreeable to those who answered this question I can merge the two, which will result in these answers being moved there.  Some editing may be necessary.

Comment: Those other answers don't use the built-in units support. You'd need to create variables for all of your conversions. With the unit based answer below you don't need to do this. You can built a simple function that has all of it built in. `toPrinterPointsMagnitude[distance_?QuantityQ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[distance, "PrinterPoints"]`. This type of fully support solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Edmund That's what I said.  It seems to be better organized, though, IMO, if these approaches were collected in one place.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Ah, ok. Yes.

Comment: @Edmund +1 to your Q and the A's, btw.  I see I made a typo above ("where" instead of "were" - oops) -- probably caused some confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

```
inches = 72;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> { 4  inches, Automatic}]
```

[image]

If you have to use `Quantity` you can set the `ImageSize` converting inches to printer points:

```
ImageSize -> { 72 QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[4, "Inches"]], Automatic}
```

**Update:** or, better yet,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle->Thick,
 ImageSize -> { 
   QuantityMagnitude[
    UnitConvert[Quantity[4, "Inches"], 
        "PrinterPoints" (* or "DesktopPublishingPoints" *)]], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the solution I'm looking for. I'd like to use the proper units as supported by Mma.  Why does 72 = 1 inch? What are the ImageSize units?

Comment: @Edmunds, please see the update...

Comment: @kguler, Very nice.  That is it! Thanks.

Comment: Impressive, as `PrinterPoints` is not listed in `QuantityUnits\`Private\`$UnitReplacementRules` and I cound't find it as a valid unit for conversion. Would that work offline?

Comment: @kguler, With this info I have made the following: `toPrinterPointsMagnitude[x_?QuantityQ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[x, "PrinterPoints"]`

Comment: I love Mathematica!!! `toPrinterPointsMagnitude[Quantity[4, "Light Year"]]` LOL!!

Comment: @rhermans, it was pure luck that the first thing i tried worked:) didn't check `$UnitReplacementRules`.

Comment: @rhermans, ... there is "DesktopPublishingPoints" that shows up when i use ``?CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`*oint*``.

Answer (score 4):

The [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) documentation, under *Details* reads:

> "Specifications for both width and height can be any of the following: "
>
> d  d printer's points (before magnification)
>
> 72di   di inches (before magnification)

So if you want 4 inches you can use:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> (72 4)]
```

for other units

```
toPrintPoints = QuantityMagnitude[72 UnitConvert[#, "Inches"]] &
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> toPrintPoints[Quantity[12, "cm"]]]
```

Comment: It seems that I'm late...

Comment: Nice solution.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I like kguler's better as I don't have to remember what 72 is.

Comment: I melded your function into kguler's solution to create: `toPrinterPointsMagnitude[x_?QuantityQ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[x, "PrinterPoints"]`. Thanks.