# Why does Mathematica set a resolution when exporting a PNG file with given pixel size?

Tags: export, image, png-format

I use the export command

```
Export[path_to_png_image,content,ImageSize->{xres,yres},Background->None]
```

to create PNG images with transparency and some fixed dimension in pixels (1280x960). Strange enough, Finder (I am on macOS) shows me a "resolution" of 144 for the exported images. Indeed, I can add the Option `ImageResolution->integer` in the export command and if I do so, Finder afterwards shows me the chosen integer as the "resolution". This makes no sense to me as the images have the same dimension in pixels and have the same file size. In principle, I could just ignore this issue, but unfortunately it matters when I import the pictures into Keynote. If I import a 1280x960 pixel image with a "resolution" of 144 into Keynote, its "Original size" according to Keynote is 640x480.

Edit: So apparently PNG has an optional header with the DPI

https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#11pHYs

which is probably controlled with ImageResolution->integer setting. But what does Mathematica exactly do when I crank up ImageResolution from 72 (what I assume is the standard resolution)? Compute more subpixels and then average over the subpixels to create one pixel?

Comment: I am not sure that this is Mathematica's doing. On Windows, if I export a PNG at a certain `ImageSize` without setting an `ImageResolution` and then import it in GIMP, then GIMP reports a 72 dpi resolution (i.e. "screen resolution"). If, on the other hand, I specify an `ImageResolution` as well, then the same image resolution is reported in GIMP as well. Not sure where the problem is. In any case, please add details on your version etc (for instance, add the output of `$Version` to your post).

Comment: `RasterSize` controls the number of pixels in the resulting image.  `ImageResolution` controls the size of said pixels.  Any app that has to deal with scaling needs to know both values in order to accurately display the image on a device.

Comment: I believe the original size in Keynote is given in points (1/72 inch). The 1280x960 dimension in pixels in Finder (in Tools>Adjust Size) with a resolution of 144 dpi corresponds to a width and height in points of 640x480 (just select points instead of pixels to verify) because 1 pixel is 1/144 inch. At a resolution of 72 dpi, 1 pixel is 1/72 inch, so points and pixels have the same magnitude. Resolution is important for display and printing but does not determine the dimensions of the image in pixels.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a Mathematica issue, but mainly a MacOS issue (and perhaps to some extent) a Keynote issue).

Comment: @m_goldberg I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is manipulating the transform between points and pixels.  Nothing more, nothing less.

It might be more illustrative if you mess around with `Rasterize` specifying both `ImageSize` and `RasterSize` and using `Information[img, "ImageResolution"]` on the result.  `Export` does have some legacy behaviors that can confuse matters.

For instance `Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[]], ImageSize -> {300, 300}, RasterSize -> {20,20}]`.

In the case of importing a PNG file with dpi included in the metadata, that allows the FrontEnd to calculate what the native `ImageSize` for that particular image should be.

Comment: Thanks, that helpful! I never actually look at the image in mathematica itself (and if I understand things correctly, ImageSize controls how the picture is displayed in mathematica). So in this case it looks to me like I have full control over the PNG parameters by just using RasterSize and ImageResolution. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you can spec just those two values.

Comment: "`Export` does have some legacy behaviors that can confuse matters." Do you mean this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101189/1871

Comment: @xzczd No.  `ImageResolution` indicates the physical size of the pixels in the image.  i.e., the number of pixels per inch.  Spec'ing `ImageResolution->500` and `ImageSize->500` (** see comment below **) means that you are setting the image to be 1 inch wide.  So in applications that care about such things (Word, Keynote, Mathematica, etc...), they will appear smaller.

Comment: The confusing part is that `Export` historically used `ImageSize` as pixels.  Which is not how it was documented, but happened to work because the renderer was not really resolution independent until 12.1.  Most uses of `ImageSize` in `Export` should be using `RasterSize` instead.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, very instructive.