# Export Long Plot with No Whitespace

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, complex, image

Observe the following code:

```
plt = ComplexPlot[Zeta[z], {z, 0 - 160*I, 3 + 160*I}, 
  ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8 + 0.5] &, None}, Frame -> None]
Export["out.png", plt, ImageResolution -> 2400];
```

It exports the following image:

https://i.ibb.co/mNMBFBv/out4.png

As you can see, there is a white background around the edges:

[image]

I'm wanting to use this plot as a texture for a 3D model. I need the white edges trimmed off. How can I specify not to include the white border in the export?

Another problem is that if I increase the resolution higher, to 4800, the entire exported image becomes solid white. I would like a high resolution export, but I'm not sure if that's possible since the height of the image becomes so extremely tall.

So two questions:

1. How do I remove the white border?
2. How do I export at resolution 4800 or higher?

Comment: Have you tried `ImageSize -> 2400` option in `ComplexPlot`?

Comment: @Somos, that gives me a distorted image. It isn't the correct aspect ratio when I use that option. See it here: https://i.ibb.co/Z6CCkGJ/out41.png

Comment: Then use `AspectRatio` option to compensate.

Comment: @Somos, please provide code that solves the issue. I don't know exactly how far off the ratio is.

Comment: Alternative is to use `ImageSize -> {width,height}` explicit dimensions.

Comment: What's the desired `ImageSize`? Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101189/1871 In your answer you've used `150/4.` as the step size, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: @xzczd, I didn't have a specific target resolution, just big enough to not be blurry. The problem is that it seems like Mathematica fails to export images once the resolution gets too big.

Comment: `4800` is way too large. On my laptop with 8GB memory, even `Rasterize[plt, RasterSize -> 2400]` results in a `Rasterize::bigraster` warning. (Do notice `Export["out.png", plt, ImageResolution -> 2400];` only results in a 135*14401 image. ) Also, the resolution of `plt` is a problem, too. Try `Show[plt, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-3, 3}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Let me extend my comments to an answer.

> How do I remove the white border?

This is the simplest part. You just need to add `PlotRangePadding -> None`. Since you want to use this plot as a texture for a 3D model, you probably need to add `BoundaryStyle -> None`, too.

> I didn't have a specific target resolution, just big enough to not be blurry.

If you care about the resolution, then you should control it from the very beginning, because the default setting of `ComplexPlot` isn't capable of generating a high-resolution image in the range `{z, 0 - 160*I, 3 + 160*I}`:

```
Show[plt, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why? Because rasterization already happens in `ComplexPlot`. (If you check the `InputForm` of the plot generated by `ComplexPlot` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, You'll find a `Image[…]` therein. ) To guarentee a high enough resolution, the `RasterSize` option must be set both in `ComplexPlot` and `Export`. (`RasterSize` gives a more straightforward control for the image size in this case, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238929/1871) for more info. )

To sum up:

```
tst = ComplexPlot[Zeta[z], {z, 0 - 160 I, 3 + 160 I}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8 + 0.5] &, None}, RasterSize -> {3, 320} 30, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> None];

Export["out.png", tst, RasterSize -> 90]
```

[image]

> How do I export at resolution 4800 or higher?

Please make sure you really need such a demanding resolution. (`RasterSize -> {3, 320} 30` already freeze my laptop with 8GB memory. ) As shown above, adjusting `ImageResolution` in `Export` won't sharpen the image in your case.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: As per comment, applying ImageCrop to the original png file will remove the white border and avoid a blurred image.

```
plt = ComplexPlot[Zeta[z], {z, 0 - 160*I, 3 + 160*I}, 
   ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8 + 0.5] &, None}, Frame -> None];
Export["out.png", plt, ImageResolution -> 2400];
Export["outCrop.png", ImageCrop@Import["out.png"]];
```

Original answer:

**ImageCrop** removes the white border. This image size is in the correct proportions and allows zooming to a reasonable size without pixelation. Of course it can be modified while maintaining the ratio.

```
plt = ComplexPlot[Zeta[z], {z, 0 - 160*I, 3 + 160*I}, 
    ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8 + 0.5] &, None}, Frame -> None]
Export["out.png", ImageCrop@plt, ImageSize -> {128, 13248}];
```

Comment: the crop seems to be applied at the lowest resolution, and then imagesize scales it up afterwards. I get a blurry mess that is useless. Did this work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I probably misunderstood what the goal was. Applying ImageCrop to your original png file will give a sharp result. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the cropping issue. However, I am still unable to export the plot correctly if Increase the image resolution to 4800 (the whole thing becomes solid white). Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and just decided to do it in Python using an export from Mathematica:

Mathematica code:

```
resolutionMultiplier = 4.0;
step = 150;
argresult = 
  ParallelTable[{x + 0.0, 
    Round[Arg[Zeta[x + I*y] + 0.0 + 0.0], 0.0001], y + 0.0}, {x, 
    0, 3, step/resolutionMultiplier}, {y, -160, 160, 
    step/resolutionMultiplier}];
Export["zeta_arg_out.txt", argresult];
```

Python code:

```
import json
import cv2
import colorsys
import math
import numpy as np

with open("zeta_arg_out.txt") as f:
  data = f.read()
  data = data.replace("{","[").replace("}","]").replace("\n",",")
  data = data.replace(".,",",").replace(".]","]")
  data = f'[{data}]'

b = json.loads(data)

xlen = len(b)
ylen = len(b[0])

img = np.array([[[0,0,0] for xx in range(xlen)] for yy in range(ylen)], dtype = np.uint8)

for xx in range(len(b)):
  print(f'{xx=}')
  for yy in range(len(b[xx])):
    val = b[xx][yy][1]/math.pi
    val = (val + 1)/2.0
    val = (val + 0.5) % 1.0
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(val,1.0,1.0)
    nc = [math.floor(ii*255) for ii in reversed(color)] # cv2 uses bgr, not rgb!
    img[yy][xx] = nc

cv2.imwrite("colormap.png", img)
```

Hopefully somebody else can post a proper Mathematica fix.