# Export of a graphics object with a fixed size

Tags: graphics, export

I am trying to generate a figure produced by `Graphics` command and export it to a pdf file having a fixed width. I followed the answer in these links, [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/imagesize-as-absolute-metric-value) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/750#750). These two solutions worked well with `Plot` and `ListPlot` as they are mentioned. However, they could not work in the same way in case of `Graphics`.
 A sample code used for testing is:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};
pts1 = Table[i + {0.5, 0.5}, {i, pts}];
Show[Graphics[{Line[pts], Line[pts1]}],  ImageSize -> {9*72/2.54, Automatic}]
Export["test.pdf", %]
```

As mentioned in the comments, followed a slightly modified code as

```
 Graphics[{Line[pts], Line[pts1]}]
 Export["test1.pdf", Show[%, ImageSize -> {9*72/2.54, Automatic}]]
```

Both the pdf files have exactly the same sized images which is 11.5cm at 100% magnification!
In the case of `Plot` and other commands, the same `Show` and `Export` commands have one scaling factor and a different one for the `Graphics` function?

Using lower dimensions in the image size could result in the desired size one wants i.e. different scaling factors for different commands.
But, How to understand this issue in a logical manner?

PS: I am working on Mathematica V 11.0.1.0

Comment: In your examples the finale size should be 9 cm, right? I got 9 cm exactly in both cases, MMA 12.0, measured in Adobe Acrobat with 100% magnification.

Comment: That's a surprise. It should be 9cm. Finally, I am using a factor to get the desired size.

Comment: May it be that this is a property of the version 11? I cannot check, since have the version 12 only. However, should this be the case I can offer a simple workaround. Add formally a Plot function to the first position under Show shuch that it draws nothing. Like this: `Show[{Plot[0, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.7}, {0, 1.5}}, 
   ImageSize -> {9*72/2.54, Automatic}], Graphics[{Line[pts], Line[pts1]}]}]`. Then Show inherits the properties of Plot.