# Rasterize: Resolution option not working properly

Tags: graphics, bugs, export, rasterize

**Bug introduced in 7 or earlier and fixed in 12.1**

<sub>Bug isn't present in version 5.2</sub>

---

Something about `Rasterize` which doesn't seem to work as intended.

Recipe:

1. **Make some simple vector graphics**:

   ```
   Test = Graphics[Circle[{0, 0} 1]]
   ```
2. **Try to rasterize** it having defined ImageSize and **ImageResolution**:

   ```
   TestNew = Rasterize[Test, "Image", ImageResolution -> 300, ImageSize -> 72]
   ```

   `ImageSize` set to 72 means that the resulting image should have exactly 1 inch in size on the screen, since screen resolution is 72 pixels per inch. This is okay.

   `ImageResolution` set 300 means that this image should have dimensions 300 over 300, since `ImageResolution` is defined in printer dots per inch and the image has the size of one inch.
3. However, **check image dimensions**:

   ```
   ImageDimensions[TestNew]
   ```

   To discover that it is 72.

Moreover: **the result does not depend at all on `ImageResolution` option**. From documentation: "`RasterSize` and `ImageResolutio`n determine the coarseness of rasterization; `ImageSize` determines the size at which the final image will be displayed." If I vary `RasterSize`, the coarseness indeed changes. If I vary `ImageResolution`, the coarseness stays the same.

**My system**: Ubuntu 14, MMA10.0.1

**Questions**:

1. Can anyone reproduce the behaviour? (**done; yes**)
2. If it's not a bug, what is the reason? (**mostly done**: technical
   reason wonderfully explained by Alexey Popkov; this will be updated
   after the answer from WRI support is available)
3. Could someone try this on older MMA versions? (**done**: See
   Alexey's comment to his answer: ImageResoltution is overriden by
   ImageSize in V7, but not in V5)

**Edit**: The result I would want to obtain in the above example can be obtained by calling:

```
TestNew = Rasterize[Test, "Image", RasterSize -> 300, ImageSize -> 72]
```

Or, for general image sizes:

```
Rasterize[Test, "Image", ImageResolution -> <DESIRED RESOLUTION IN DPI>, ImageSize -> (<DESIRED SIZE IN CENTIMETERS>)*(72/2.54)]
```

should give the same result as:

```
Rasterize[Test, "Image", RasterSize -> (<DESIRED SIZE IN CENTIMETERS>/2.54)*(<DESIRED RESOLUTION IN DPI>), ImageSize -> (<DESIRED SIZE IN CENTIMETERS>)*(72/2.54)]
```

In other words, `ImageResolution` and `RasterSize` seem to serve the same purpose, but the former one doesn't seem to work as it should.

**Status update**: According to the feedback from WRI: The question has been acknowledged as an issue. However it is not decided yet, how exactly it is to be resolved.

Comment: Don't know much about `Rasterize`, but `TestNew = 
 Rasterize[Test, "Image", ImageResolution -> 300, ImageSize -> 300]` returns a 300 by 300 image. So perhaps `Rasterize` uses whichever of `ImageSize` and `ImageResolution` is smaller? If so, then I agree that doesn't make much sense. As a more extreme example, `Rasterize[Test, "Image", ImageResolution -> 0, ImageSize -> 600]` gives a 600x600 image. So it almost looks like `ImageSize` overrides `ImageResolution`. Can anyone confirm this? The documentation says `RasterSize` overrides `ImageResolution`, but doesn't say anything about `ImageSize`.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: Yes, exactly, overrides. In fact, for any fixed ImageSize varying the value of resolution does take no effect. RasterSize is also an option which is responsible for "resolution" of the image (number of pixel dots in it). ImageSize is rather the size of the image on the screen, or equivalent physical size of the image on the paper. Therefore, one would expect ImageResolution option to behave similarly to RasterSize option.

Comment: Related: [(5442)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5442/121)

Comment: And also very useful notes on exporting graphics I found in Szabolics answer [here][1]. However, in both above links the focus on how to export graphics properly. Whilst this question is on why does Rasterize not function quite as properly as it supposedly should.


  [1]: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/750#750

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a bit of spelunking I extracted the following from

```
g = Graphics[{Circle[], FontSize -> 20, Text["x^2+y^2<1", {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 72];
Trace[Rasterize[g, ImageSize -> 72, ImageResolution -> 100]]
```

in v.10.0.1.

---

### An excerpt from the `Trace` output

1) At first, the value of `RasterSize` is extracted from the `Rasterize` command using `OptionValue`:

```
System`ConvertersDump`rs$ = 
 OptionValue[Rasterize, {ImageSize -> 72, ImageResolution -> 100}, RasterSize]
```

> ```
> Automatic
> ```

2) In our case `RasterSize` is `Automatic` (the default value) and hence on the following line the value of `ImageSize` option (which has dimensionality of [*printer's points*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)#Current_DTP_point_system), i.e. the base unit is *inch*) is incorrectly taken as `RasterSize` (which has dimensionality of *pixels*) without taking into consideration `ImageResolution`:

```
If[System`ConvertersDump`rs$ === Automatic, 
      System`ConvertersDump`rs$ = 
        OptionValue[Rasterize, {ImageSize -> 72, ImageResolution -> 100}, 
         ImageSize]]
```

> ```
> 72
> ```

3) Now the new value for `RasterSize` is converted into the form `{width, heigh}`:

```
If[! ListQ[System`ConvertersDump`rs$] || Length[System`ConvertersDump`rs$] != 2, 
 System`ConvertersDump`rs$ = {System`ConvertersDump`rs$, Automatic}]
```

> ```
> {72, Automatic}
> ```

4) At the next step final image resolution is calculated from the **new** `RasterSize` (note that the original `ImageResolution` is present but ignored!):

```
{System`ConvertersDump`w$, System`ConvertersDump`h$} = System`ConvertersDump`rs$;

System`ConvertersDump`ir$ = 
     System`ConvertersDump`GetIR[
      Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], FontSize -> 20, Text["x^2+y^2<1", {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 72], 
       {System`ConvertersDump`w$, System`ConvertersDump`h$}, 
           ImageSize -> 72, ImageResolution -> 100]
```

> ```
> 72
> ```

5) And finally the packet is constructed using the **obtained** value for `ImageResolution`:

```
System`ConvertersDump`rdpdata$ = 
     System`ConvertersDump`ToRasterDataPacket[
       Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], FontSize -> 20, Text["x^2+y^2<1", {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 72], 
       {"Rasterize", "BoundingBox"}, 
       ImageResolution -> System`ConvertersDump`ir$, Background -> System`ConvertersDump`bg$, 
       ColorSpace -> System`ConvertersDump`cs$, 
       Sequence @@ 
         FilterRules[{ImageSize -> 72, ImageResolution -> 100}, 
         Except[{ImageResolution, Background, ColorSpace}]]]
```

---

### What happens when `ImageSize` is not specified

When `ImageSize` is not specified, everything is the same up to the step 4):

```
System`ConvertersDump`ir$ = 
     System`ConvertersDump`GetIR[
      Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], FontSize -> 20, Text["x^2+y^2<1", {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 72], 
       {System`ConvertersDump`w$, System`ConvertersDump`h$}, 
           ImageResolution -> 100]
```

> ```
> 100
> ```

We see that when the **new** value of `RasterSize` is `{Automatic, Automatic}` the original value of `ImageResolution` is taken as the final value for image resolution **at this step**.

---

### Conclusion

From the above it is clear that the key option which *currently* determines the image resolution in `Rasterize` is not `ImageResolution` but `RasterSize`.

The mechanism of the inconsistent behavior described in the question is as follows: when non-`Automatic` `ImageSize` is specified *without `RasterSize`* it is taken as `ImageResolution`. This contradicts to the documented meaning of these options: `ImageSize` specifies the size of the image in *printer's points* where *inch* is the base unit while `ImageResolution` has dimensionality of *dots per inch*.

At the same time the combination `RasterSize` + `ImageSize` works as expected in accord with the Documentation. So the workaround is to use `RasterSize` and do not rely on `ImageResolution`.

Comment: Thanks for an amazing answer and a wonderful spelunking tour! It might be a bug, it seems. Would probably be useful if someone could check for this in older versions. Will forward to WRI, for starters.

Comment: I have checked it in versions 5.2 and 7.0.1. In version 5.2 the code `Export["test.tiff",Graphics[{Circle[{0,0},{2,1}],Text["x^2+y^2<1",{0,0}]}],ImageSize->72,ImageResolution->300]` exports correct TIFF with resolution 300 dpi and width 1 inch, while in version 7.0.1 it exports with resolution 72 dpi. Considering also [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica#comment1911_737) we can conclude that the bug was introduced in v.6 or 7.

Comment: Thanks greatly for checking this! Yes, one would indeed think it useful to use ImageSize and ImageResolution in combination. Even more importantly, it is not so hard to overlook that Resolution setting does not work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have time for a complete answer at the moment but hopefully this helps.  I believe that `ImageSize`, if specified directly inside `Rasterize`, overrides the `ImageResolution`.  Observe this behavior when `ImageSize` is used in `Graphics` instead:

```
g = Graphics[{Circle[], FontSize -> 20, Text["x^2+y^2<1", {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 130];

r = Table[Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> r], {r, {20, 40, 100}}]
```

[image]

---

## An examination of `ImageSize`

Since my original post Alexey Popkov provided a much deeper analysis but pragmatically the conclusion is the same: when `ImageSize` is given as an option of `Rasterize` it overrides `ImageResolution`, but when `ImageSize` is given as part of a `Graphics` expression `ImageResolution` has effect.

A question remains as to the intended (or desired) behavior in this case.  Alexey correctly notes that [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) is ostensibly defined in printer's points:

> *d*                         *d* printer's points (before magnification)

However I find this to be *practically* false.  If you specify an `ImageSize` of `100` you get an image that is 100 pixels wide.  This equivalence requires a *resolution* of 72 pixels per inch (assuming PostScript printer's points).  This resolution is highly outdated as modern displays different resolutions that are often much higher.

*Mathematica* is aware of the OS-specified resolution.  For example under Windows 7 I have "Medium" selected which sets the OS to 120ppi and *Mathematica* knows this:

```
CurrentValue["ScreenResolution"]
```

> ```
> {120, 120}
> ```

Nevertheless the Front End *ignores* this resolution and renders my `ImageSize -> 100` graphic as 100 *pixels* wide rather than 167 pixels wide as it would if `ImageSize` *really* meant printer's point and not pixels.  Further there is a System Option for screen resolution and it too is ignored:

[image]

This setting has no effect that I have observed on `ImageSize` rendering.

There is the setting `"ScreenResolution"` under `"FontProperties"` that does have effect but only on font size.  Observe this example where `FontSize -> 20` is correctly rendered at different specified resolutions:

```
Graphics[{"FontProperties" -> {"ScreenResolution" -> #}, Circle[], FontSize -> 20, 
    Text["x^2+y^2<1", {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 130] & /@ {30, 60, 100}
```

[image]

**I must conclude that by convention and the documentation notwithstanding `ImageSize` is in actuality specified in pixel dimension, not printer's points, as far as the Front End is concerned.**

Therefore it is entirely reasonable that if an absolute `ImageSize` is given to `Rasterize` it will use this value rather than one derived from `ImageResolution`.  I therefore further conclude that this behavior is *not* a bug.  However the entire disregarding of screen resolution by the Front End and the effective specification of `ImageSize` in pixels might be.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I am aware that ImageResolution works on its own. However, ImageSize is not supposed to override ImageResolution. For example, it does not override RasterSize, which serves the same function roughly, as ImageResolution.

Comment: I have added more information on this in the question edit.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You have not specified the second argument of `Rasterize` as `"Image"` and you get `Graphics` object instead. This is the reason why you get roughly equal `ImageDimensions` in all cases: all of them are equal to `ImageSize` and do not reflect actual resolution of the `Raster` object inside of `Graphics`. Use `Dimensions /@ r[[All, 1, 1]]` for obtaining actual information.

Comment: @Alexey that is what I was alluding to with "There is more than one kind of image size in play here."

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion based on the apparent rendering in the FrontEnd. First of all, `CurrentValue["ScreenResolution"]` is undocumented option and we should not expect that it works correctly or supported. For on-screen rendering `ImageSize` seemingly means just *pixel size* and I consider this as another example of promised but not implemented functionality. But for `Rasterize` and `Export` *Mathematica* apparently uses *[the desktop publishing point (DTP point)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#Current_DTP_point_system)* equal to 1/72 of inch for `ImageSize`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for your feedback!  By Front End I meant the display rendering, not export functionality.  I guess my point is that if we don't expect the *display aspect* of the Front End to implement `ImageSize` in printer's points we should also not expect `Rasterize` to handle it correctly; frankly it would surprise me if it did.  Regarding your second comment: I agree this should work as documented, but for that to happen the Front End needs to start respecting screen resolution, at least via the existing `ScreenResolution` option in the Option Inspector.

Comment: As we know it is possible (and not too hard) to force `Rasterize` to handle `ImageResolution` correctly. It already correctly handles `RasterSize` with `ImageSize` in accord with the Documentation. So I think that WRI just prioritize `Export` over on-screen rendering and I think that it is reasonable choice.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I know that `CurrentValue["ScreenResolution"]` is undocumented but it demonstrates that the software already reads this value from the OS.  `ScreenResolution` however is right there in the Option Inspector.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't think it is reasonable to make `ImageSize` defined in pixels in one place and printer's points in another.  Presently the documentation *does not* say that `ImageSize` means pixels to the Front End, with the exception of export and `Rasterize`.  By your own definition that is a BUG I believe.

Comment: I did not mean that it is reasonable to define `ImageSize` ambiguously. I mean that it is reasonable to set higher priority for `Export`-related functionality as compared to on-screen rendering while the latter works satisfactory well. In this perspective the ambiguous `ImageSize` case is just gedanken functionality and is *semi*-bug because the necessary `ScreenResolution` functionality is still under-implemented.

Comment: I would counter your conclusion by mentioning that in documentation ImageResolution and RasterSize option always go together and have vaguely the same meaning (see the edit to my question). One would intuitively want ImageResolution to produce an effect similar to that by RasterSize.

Comment: It is indeed ImageSize which defines pixel point size of the image. Therefore the printing point size is a free variable, which is meant to be defined.