# Rasterize alters the quality of the figure

Tags: graphics, export, image, rasterize

A quick 3D plot

```
P1 = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
Mesh -> None, BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

which looks like

[image]

Then I rasterize the image and I export it as an EPS file

```
rast = Rasterize[P1, RasterSize -> 2000, ImageSize -> 550];
E0 = Export["test.eps", rast, "EPS"];
```

However when I open the EPS file I see that the thickness of the bounding box is missing.

[image]

Is is a bug or I have to use another option so as to keep the style of the bounding box? I use version 9.0 in Windows XP. I have to rasterize the 3D plot instead of `E0 = Export["test.eps", P1, "EPS"];` otherwise the EPS file has huge size (more than 100 MB) and in many cases the program crashes.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an explicit thickness, eg `Thickness[.01]` instead of the generic `Thick`

Comment: @george2079 Yes, it's working. Do we know why the generic `Thick` fail? If you want post a quick answer so as to approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [george2079 correctly points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102932/rasterize-alters-the-quality-of-the-figure#comment279542_102932) in the comment, the source of the problem is that you specify thickness of the bounding box as `Thick` which is evaluated to

```
Thick
```

> ```
> Thickness[Large]
> ```

According to the [Documentation page for `Thickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thickness.html) (see under "Details" section),

> The following symbolic forms for $r$ can be used: `Tiny`, `Small`,
>   `Medium`, and `Large`. These specify **absolute thicknesses independent**
>   **of the overall size of the graphic**.

(emphasis mine). This meas that the larger size of the graph you request from `Rasterize`, the thinner bounding box you obtain. So if you need to make the appearance independent from the size of the graphics you should not use absolute thickness but use relative `Thickness` (with numeric argument) instead.

And here appears one principal difficulty/ambiguity in how this behavior is documented and how it actually works. It is reasonable to expect that when you specify `ImageSize -> 550` you then need not to worry anymore about your thickness irrespectively of which `RasterSize` (which changes only resolution of the raster image) you specify. It is because according to [Documentation page for `ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) *Mathematica* assumes that `ImageSize` is specified in *printer's points*, while [`AbsoluteThickness` is **also** specified in *printer's points*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteThickness.html). So it is very natural to expect that when you specify `AbsoluteThickness` the resulting appearance will not depend on the image resolution! But in the reality `AbsoluteThickness` is linked not to `ImageSize` but to `RasterSize` in contradiction with the Documentation!

In [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64758/280) I provide additional arguments and considerations in support of my view that current behavior is inconsistent and wrong. At the bottom of the question in that thread a response from WRI acknowledging this issue is published. Nevertheless I suggest you to report current behavior as a bug again because it moves the problem higher in the WRI's bug priority list.