# Can styles be exported in EPS as simple text tags for use by LaTeX's psfrag?

Tags: export, latex

Is there a way to export graphics as EPS so that *LaTeX* can perform style substitutions or modifications on them?

I know that it is possible to [replace simple text elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/740/37) in imported EPS files using *LaTeX's* `psfrag`; but if this is all that is possible, it is not sufficient to enforce a consistent appearance for graphics. That requires the ability to make substitutions to things like line weights and colors.

Is there a way to use Mathematica to export EPS files in such a way that style elements are represented as simple text tags that can be easily replaced using `psfrag` (or a similar technique) in *LaTeX*?

Comment: I think it is an interesting question, but the +1 is for the name.

Comment: There is a package called mathpsfrag  http://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld: That seems to be old (it complains mightily when installed under 8.0; and many questions related to it here and on TeX.SE are unanswered). It also isn't clear to me how to get it to do what I wold want: simply set up the EPS so that I can perform simple `psfrag` (or similar) substitutions on the LaTeX (import) end.

Comment: If you want to do all the final controls with latex, then it might be better to export the points for your curve and import them and plot with tikz

Comment: Yes, that's a good suggestion, and it seems by far the simplest in any scenario where the meat of the figure can be reduced to a function. My question extends to scenarios where this is not the case; e.g., the Mathematica figure is of something like this. Could I, say, make the black squares a specific blue in LaTeX?