# Font difference in mathematica 9 and 10 after export to illustrator

Tags: version-9, version-10, fonts

It seems WRI has changed the way fonts are dealt with in Mathematica 9 and 10.

The following command

```
Export["test.eps", "This is a nice formula"]
```

yields this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

in Mathematica 9 (after import to Illustrator)

whereas it yields

[image: Mathematica graphics]

in Mathematica 10. In other words, the font it *not recognized anymore* by Illustrator CS3. This is using Macos X.

I have tried uploading the Mathematica fonts from http://support.wolfram.com/kb/10427
but it does not seem to help.

> Any ideas? 
>   (My apologies for a possibly silly question)

### Update

Following @Szabolcs remark I tried

```
Export["test.pdf", "This is a nice formula"]
```

In Mathematica 9 I get a 1.3 Mb (!!) file which works fine in Illustrator

In Mathematica 10 I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is hardly progress!

Comment: All the fonts seem to have been outlined, which means that there's no way to get the text back once the EPS has been written.  If you use PDF, this doesn't happen.  In the v10 betas, even exporting to PDF would outline the fonts, but fortunately this was fixed.  I almost never use EPS so didn't notice that with EPS it still happens (I complained about PDF during the beta).  I wonder if there's an option to control this.

Comment: Thanks! What a drag… I ll try and go through PDF then.

Comment: @Szabolcs I also just noticed this new font outlining "bug" with EPS export (it breaks some of my old [psfrag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6386507/421225) [tricks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/740/34)). Have you filed a bug report with WRI?

Comment: no because I was not sure if it were a bug or a feature!

Comment: @Simon, I did report on the fact that psfrag cannot connect to MMA10, a while ago.

Comment: "I could see that the labels are not being identified and converted by PSfrag. I cannot comment on PSfrag compatibility with Mathematica as it's an external package, however, I added your contact information to an existing suggestion for better compatibility with LaTeX fonts and styles.  In my tests, the EPS files created by Mathematica 10 are opened successfully by other viewers.  There were changes in how the plot labels are stored in the EPS file, but still within the PS-3 standard. I did not find an option for reverting to the older method of including text. ...

Comment: ... 
Mathematica has a feature where two versions can co-exist on a machine. Since PSfrag appears to be essential for your LaTeX preparation, it would be reasonable for you to continue using Mathematica 9 for your needs. It is common for customers to have two versions installed, especially during the transition after release of a new version." It does seem to be a feature, rather than a bug.