# How do I make a string literal without having to escape backslashes?

Tags: string-manipulation, core-language, input-forms

I'd like to say something like:

```
foo = @"\abc\def\ghi"
```

instead of

```
foo = "\\abc\\def\\ghi"
```

How do I do this?  This would be really nice for regular expressions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I think that answers to this question should address cases when one is working directly in the Kernel without a front-end or with another front-end like Jupyter notebook and Wolfram Engine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can implement a raw string syntax using the global variable [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PreRead.html), which "is applied to the text or box form of every input expression before it is fed to the Wolfram Language." Using `$PreRead`, we can get at the string before any interpretation has been performed on it, replace it with the corresponding `InputForm` expression, and send that along as input to *Mathematica*.

Here we define a `RawString` "head" that signals that the `RawString` expression will be automatically replaced by the `InputForm` of its argument before being used as input:

```
$PreRead = (
  # /. RowBox@{"RawString", "[", str_String, "]"} | 
       RowBox@{"RawString", "@", str_String} | 
       RowBox@{str_String, "//", "RawString"} :> 
         RowBox@{"StringTrim", "[", ToString@InputForm@str, ",", "\"\\\"\"", "]"}
)&;
```

Note that we are dealing with the box form prior to any evaluation, so we have to use separate patterns for prefix and postfix notation. The `StringTrim` is inserted so that it will take effect after the input string is interpreted to remove the extraneous opening and closing quotes.

Now we can enter

```
"\abc\def\ghi\nop" // RawString
```

or

```
RawString@"\abc\def\ghi\nop"
```

and we get

```
\abc\def\ghi\nop
```

The `RawString` expressions can be part of other expressions:

```
RawString@"\pi\ " <> RawString@"\nu\ "
(* \pi\ \nu\ *)
```

as long as each raw string is explicitly the argument of a `RawString`, i.e.,

```
RawString /@ {"\pi\ ", "\nu\ "}
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

To enter the string in without double backslash, you could use a [`TextCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TextCell.html) as follows:

> `ToString@@`<kbd>Ctrl-9</kbd>\abc\def\ghi<kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd>
>
> \abc\def\ghi

```
FullForm[%]
```

> "\\abc\\def\\ghi"

On the first line, I open a text cell and enter the text as you wanted to type it. The `ToString` knows how to convert the text cell to a string, as is shown in the last `FullForm` output.

You could also replace `ToString@@` by `First@`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a direct input form as you describe but *Mathematica* will insert the escapes for you in the right circumstance.  If you copy the verbatim text `\abc\def\ghi\nop` and paste it between quotation marks in a Notebook you will get a dialog:

[image]

Click **Yes** and you get:

> ```
> "\\abc\\def\\ghi\\nop"
> ```

If the string is in an external file [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) will handle it correctly.  For example if we put `\abc\def\ghi\nop` in a file named `foo.txt` we can then use:

```
Import["foo.txt", "String"] // FullForm
```

> ```
> "\\abc\\def\\ghi\\nop"
> ```

The [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) is added merely to show that the escaped `\\` are in fact present.

Comment: What if one is working directly in the Kernel, and no front-end or with another front-end like Jupyter notebook and Wolfram Engine?