# Input a non-string input -- output as a string

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, latex

I am trying to create a function that needs to transform its input into a string. The objective is to transform a $\LaTeX$ mathematical expression into an executable *Mathematica* expression.

```
latextoma[x_] := ToExpression[InputForm[x], TeXForm]
```

Here, I'm trying to use `InputForm` because the function needs to accept inputs of the following form:

```
\sum_ {n = 1}^{4} 0.9^{n - 1} (1 - 0.9)
```

*Ideally, the input would **not** be a string.* Is there any way I can tell the function to work with this input as a string?

Comment: I don't think mathematica could possibly accept `f[\...`. The question is, where does the input come from? I do recall, however, that there was a related question somewhere here, about forcing Mathematica to take input verbatim. Is it completely out of the question to wrap the input in quotes?

Comment: Where would this input come from?

Comment: I agree with @LLlAMnYP that I don't see how a MMA function could accept input starting with `\s` (or even how one could feed such input to a function, for that matter!). I think the key here is where you get your expressions, as others have mentioned. Also, why would it be ideal for your input *not* to be a string? It actually seems to complicate things quite a bit. Finally, if you don't want your resulting expression to be automatically evaluated, you may want to have `ToExpression` wrap it in `HoldForm`, i.e. `ToExpression[x, TeXForm, HoldForm]`.

Comment: The expression is a Latex expression; but I suppose I may be asking too much. Is there a way to make mathematica automatically always interpret the stuff I copy from latex as InputForm? It always pops up a warning asking me about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to get *Mathematica* to accept `TeXForm` input in raw form without quotes, using a method similar to the one described [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86910/8253).

Using `$PreRead` to intercept the input before it is interpreted by *Mathematica* and then convert it to a string, we can define the `latextoma` function as a replacement rule with

```
$PreRead = (# /. RowBox@{"latextoma", "[", expr__, "]"} :> 
  RowBox@{"ToExpression[", 
    ToString@InputForm@StringJoin@Cases[{expr}, _String, \[Infinity]], 
    ", TeXForm]"
  }
) &;
```

Here, `$PreRead` gets the input in box form, `Cases` and `StringJoin` picks out and reassembles the input in its original form, and `InputForm` and `ToString` adds the necessary quotes and escape characters. Then the box form of `ToExpression` is inserted so that it will take effect when the input is interpreted. Any whitespace in the input is lost during this procedure; luckily, $\LaTeX$ ignores most whitespace as well, so that's not too much of an issue.

Now we can do (look ma, no quotes!):

```
latextoma[\sum_ {n = 1}^{m} n^2]
```

> `1/6 m (1 + m) (1 + 2 m)`

There may be ways to break this, though -- you'd have to decide if the benefit is worth the potential trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
ToString[FromCharacterCode[92]] <> "\sum_{n = 1}^{4} 0.9^{n - 1} (1 - 0.9)"
```

(*

\\sum_{n = 1}^{4} 0.9^{n - 1} (1 - 0.9)

*)

Comment: The idea is to make the function automatically write the '\sum_{n = 1}^{4} 0.9^{n - 1} (1 - 0.9)' part as "\\sum_{n = 1}^{4} 0.9^{n - 1} (1 - 0.9)", instead of manually doing it. Thats why I need the input form.