# How to display a formula written in proper LaTeX (e.g. no double backslashes) in Mathematica?

Tags: replacement, latex, display

I would like to display some formulae in a Mathematica notebook. For this I would like to have a function like

```
DisplayLaTeX[latex_String] := Module[{modlatex},
modlatex:=StringReplace[latex,"\\"->"\\\\"];
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[DisplayForm@ToExpression[modlatex, TeXForm, HoldForm]]], "Text"]
];
```

taking regular LaTeX syntax (with only single backslashes) as an input.

With the above approach, Mathematica already evaluates escape sequences like \f, \s, ... before doing the `StringReplace` and thus renders expressions like

```
DisplayLaTeX["\zeta(n_1,\ldots,n_r)=\sum_{0<k_1<\cdots<k_r}\frac{1}{k_1^{n_1}\cdots k_r^{n_r}}"]
```

incorrectly. What would be the correct way to achieve a proper rendering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a string literal without having to escape backslashes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76647/how-do-i-make-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-backslashes) Long story short: Backslashes work as [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in Mathematica (and many other languages. That is why you have to properly escape them with another backslash. If you want to bypass this, you can use a solution from the answer mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Domen's recommendation, I could indeed create the expected behaviour by using the common variable `$PreRead` in Mathematica. Here is the function rendering simple LaTeX commands:

```
$PreRead = (
  # /. RowBox@{"DisplayLaTeX", "[", str_String, "]"} | 
       RowBox@{"DisplayLaTeX", "@", str_String} | 
       RowBox@{str_String, "//", "DisplayLaTeX"} :> 
         RowBox@{"DisplayLaTeXHelper", "[","StringTrim", "[", ToString@InputForm@str, ",", "\"\\\"\"", "]","]"}
)&;

DisplayLaTeXHelper[latex_String] := Module[{},
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[DisplayForm@ToExpression[latex, TeXForm, HoldForm]]], "Text"]
];
```

Using the following command one can now display the definition of multiple zeta values:

```
DisplayLaTeX["\zeta(n_1,\ldots,n_r)=\sum_{0<k_1<\cdots<k_r}\frac{1}{k_1^{n_1}\cdots k_r^{n_r}}"]
```

The only downside of this method is that autocompletion for DisplayLaTeX won't work.