# How to type this certain expression (duplicate question for reference purpose)?

Tags: formatting

In graphing I hope to output the following format for example $|a_{1020}|^2$.

I need to use this as my axes label in a plot and to type this expression in *Mathematica*. I am fully aware there is a guideline post. This question (with an answer below) serves as a specific case (some elements may quite commonly occur in graphing) for future reader. If not, please close this question but do not downvote it.

If kindly uplift the downvote as I am closed to getting banned due to this one question. If you find this question useful as a special case, please upvote it.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943.  Possibly a duplicate if the apparent TeX form above is what is specifically desired.

Comment: kwy, I am provisionally closing this as a duplicate of the post linked by Michael above.  If you feel that your question is *not* answered there please edit your Question to explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TraditionalForm[Abs[Subscript[a,1020]]^2]
```

Comment: Thanks @yohbs. I have add one more picture. The output of mathematica results in a spacing for long-digit number. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Use quotes to force Mathematica to treat stuff as strings and not as numbers/variabels.  `TraditionalForm[Abs[Subscript["a", "102900"]]^2]`