# Export Plot to PDF results very messy

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

When my nice looking [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html) results are exported as [PDF](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDF.html), they look very different from the original plots. For example, my original plot in Mathematica looks like

[image]

When this is exported as PDF, I have

[image]

**Is there anyway I can export my plots exactly as they look?**

EDIT

My model is a discrete dynamic model consisted of around ten variables and ten equations. So I used `DiscretePlot`, not `Plot`.

My code is:

```
a1 = 0.85;
a2 = 0.25;
L1 = 0.07;
L2 = 0.3;
w = 2;
b1 = 1;
b2 = 0.2;
x1[0] = 1;
x2[0] = 1;
p1[0] = 0.5;
p2[0] = 0.2;
mul0 = 0.9
mul1 = 3.9
mul2 = 2.8
H[0] = 1
r[0] = 0.1
```

```
x1[t_] := x1[t] = G*x1[t - 1];
x2[t_] := x2[t] = G*x2[t - 1];
mul[t_] := mul[t] = mul0 + mul1*r[t - 1] + mul2*(G - 1)
H[t_] := H[t] = H[t - 1]*G
m[t_] := m[t] = (mul[t]*H[t])/(L1*x1[t] + L2*x2[t])
exp[t_] := exp[t] = (m[t] - p2[t - 1]*w)/(p2[t - 1]*w)
r[t_] := r[t] = (exp[t]*(p2[t - 1]*w*L1*x1[t] + 
   p2[t - 1]*w*L2*x2[t]))/((p1[t - 1]*a1 + p2[t - 1]*w*L1)*
  x1[t] + (p1[t - 1]*a2 + p2[t - 1]*w*L2)*x2[t])
p1[t_] := p1[t] = (1 + r[t])*(p1[t - 1]*a1 + p2[t - 1]*w*L1)
p2[t_] := p2[t] = (1 + r[t])*(p1[t - 1]*a2 + p2[t - 1]*w*L2)
check[t_] := check[t] = (x1[t] - a1 x1[t] - a2 x2[t])*p1[t] +
x2[t]*p2[t] -m[t]*(L1*x1[t] + L2*x2[t])
```

```
n1 = 1;
n2 = 200
```

```
Plot3 = Show[GraphicsRow[{DiscretePlot[p1[t], {t, n1, n2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Price 1", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{n1, n2}, {0, 10}}, Filling -> None, 
 Joined -> True], 
DiscretePlot[v1[t], {t, n1, n2}, PlotLabel -> "Price 2", 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}, PlotRange -> {{n1, n2}, {0, 5}}, 
 Filling -> None, Joined -> True], 
DiscretePlot[check[t], {t, n1, n2}, PlotLabel -> "check", 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}, PlotRange -> {{n1, n2}, {0, 10}}, 
 Filling -> None, Joined -> True]}], ImageSize -> Full]
Export["Plot3.pdf", Plot3];
```

> 

Comment: Please always add code to enable reproduction of your exact situation. Otherwise other people may waste time guessing what you did.

Comment: This question will be easier to answer and more useful for others if you add a minimal working example of working code and data to show specifically what you are working with. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Include a minimum example of code that shows the problem and an example of the desired output.

Comment: I personally stopped trying to get Graphics exported as .pdf altogether and usually use .eps instead and imbed/convert to .pdf in my external software (Adobe Illustrator, Latex ...)

Comment: Probably the only surefire (and rather uninspired)  approach to excatly reproduce screen appearance  is to `Rasterize` at suitable resolution and export in `PNG` or similar lossless bitmap format. Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the cell with the plots
2. Copy-paste into a new empty notebook
3. File -> Printing Settings -> Page Setup...
4. Choose paper size A3 and landscape
5. Save as a new pdf
6. Go to https://www.cutepdf-editor.com/edit.asp
7. Upload pdf and crop it and save it

I have experienced that some of the symbols from mathematica (such as capital gamma) appear wrong when the file is loaded in cutepdf, but when I save them and open in adobe reader, they are right again.

Answer (score 3):

How are you producing the pdf?  What operating system are you using?  You haven't included any code, but in my attempt I don't reproduce your problem,

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[(20 Exp[-t/2] + 2 Exp[-t/20] Cos[t] + 3), {t, 0, 50}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Price 1"],
  Plot[(30 Exp[-t/2] - 2 Exp[-t/5] Cos[t] + 14), {t, 0, 50}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Price 2"],
  Plot[(2 Exp[-t/2] - 2 Exp[-t/25] Cos[t] + 6), {t, 0, 50}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Price is Right"]}, ImageSize -> 700]
Export["pricecheck.pdf", %]
```

and here is a comparison of the results

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! In fact, I used `DiscretePlot`. I added my code. Any followup would be greatly appreciated!