# Saving contourplot with high quality

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, export

I have plotted a colored figure using contourplot. What is the best way to save it so that its quality becomes higher? I want it use in Latex.

Comment: `Export["fig.pdf", plot]`; or with `.eps` if you prefer.

Comment: Higher than what?  What have you tried?

Comment: I used save graphics as.. . PNG @Szabolcs

Comment: `.png` typically works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use pdflatex, I recommend:

- PDF for line art
- PNG when PDF doesn't produce an acceptable result
- JPEG for photos

Use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) instead of Save Graphics As.

```
plot = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

First try

```
Export["plot.pdf", plot]
```

If the result is not acceptable, try

```
Export["plot.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 4*72]
```

The default image resolution is 72 dpi.  Use `4*72` to get a four times larger image.  Find the correct size for your needs.

See also:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12