# How to set margins and paper orientation when exporting to PDF

Tags: export

I want for example export a simple plot to a PDF file. The paper orientation should be portrait and the printing margings should have a certain value.

I tried the following:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

Export[StringJoin["Sin.pdf"], p, "PDF", 
  PrintingOptions -> {"PrintingMargins" -> {{300, 300}, {300, 300}}, 
                      "PaperOrientation" -> "Portrait"}];
```

but it gives me the follwing image of the PDF file which is not portrait and has no margins:

[image]

Comment: That's not how it works.  There is no paper size.  Plots are exported at their *actual size*.  What size of paper you want to print this on later is not factored into the equation. [Read this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12) on how to export to a precise size.  Check ImageMargins and ImagePadding to add extra space around the plot. Check the documentation for what units these options use.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you for this information. I am only surprised that I do not get any message after executing the upper `Export` command.

Comment: `Export` is a bit weird. The allowed options are different for each format, and it does not always warn if some incorrect option names are given. It just ignores them.

Comment: BTW when saving a *notebook* (not Graphics), there *is* a paper size.  A starting point for a workaround could be `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Full]`, then File -> Save As... and save the notebook as PDF.  This could be automated.  Notebooks (handles like the one returned by `EvaluationNotebook[]`, or explicit `Notebook` expressions) can be exported to PDF with `Export`.  In this case the page size matters.  `ImageSize -> Full` makes the figure as wide as the available space. There would be more work to remove the cell labels, and I do not know how to centre vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a whole "page" pdf you can do like this:

```
p = Show[{Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[White], 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {612, 792}], Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]}]}]
Export["Sin.pdf", p, "PDF", ImageSize -> {612, 792}];
```

Play with the options to inset to control the size/placement.