# How to set labelstyle into latex?

Tags: labeling, latex

I have a picture to draw. But I want to set the label of axis like

[image]

If you know how to set this, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [MaTeX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/76943#76943)?

Comment: I didn't know MaTeX before. I try it by MaTeX now.

Comment: @zhk Thanks for your help.I have done it by MaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

```
<< MaTeX`

Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"\\text{$V_0$ axis}", "\\mathrm{v}_{0}"}]
```

[image]