# Scale plot labels

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

How can I configure the plot labels so that when I scale the plot (either manually or producing a high-resolution rasterized version of it), they scale too? Basically, I want the labels to take up a constant fraction of the overall plot no matter what size the plot is

Comment: does  the option  `LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.05]}` give you what you need?

Comment: @kglr Why did you delete it?  I *was* the answer to the literal question, and it had a good example in it. I was just about to upvote.

Comment: @Szabolcs,  deleted until i could figure out how to deal with the gap between the plot label and the plot at  different image sizes. Then I saw your answer:)

Answer (score 3):

To show the plot or just about any part of the notebook in larger size, you can use [`Magnify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Magnify.html).  You can also set the magnification option of the notebook (lower right corner).

To rasterize with higher resolution, *set the resolution*, not the image size.

```
Rasterize[..., ImageResolution -> a 72]
```

will rasterize at a size `a` times larger than the `ImageSize`, if you like to count in pixels, or at `a 72` dpi if you like to think in terms of printing.

---

You *can* specify the font size in [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) units to allow text to scale when you resize the image, but *I do not recommend this*.  Instead, I suggest to prepare figures to a certain print size [as I described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12).  This will make it easy to match up the size of the text in your figure with the surrounding text if the figure will be inserted into a document. It also allows you to rasterize at the correct print resolution (typically 600 dpi for line art).

I wrote about these ideas in:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12
- The "Preparing Figures to Size" tutorial included in the [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) documentation.