# TeXForm as PlotLabels (Configuring GhostScript?)

Tags: labeling, text, latex

**Update**

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
    "pdfLaTeX" -> 
    "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64", 
    "Ghostscript" -> "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.23\\bin"
]
```

`CAN NOT` work!!!! Help manual is misleading in this case. But I suppose the author only uses MAC OS and could not test it.

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
    "pdfLaTeX" -> 
    "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\pdflatex.exe", 
    "Ghostscript" -> "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.23\\bin\\gswin64c.exe"
]
```

Finally worked for `MaTeX`. But the main problem still remains.

I want to do something similar to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/),

```
myplot[a_, b_] :=   Plot[a*Sin[b*x], {x, -Pi, Pi},    PlotLabel ->     TeXForm["$a=" <> ToString[a] <> ", b=" <> ToString[b] <> "$"]];
myplot[5, 4]
```

Does not work.

Also tried something like this,

```
myplot2[a_, b_] :=   Plot[a*Sin[b*x], {x, -Pi, Pi},    PlotLabel ->     ToExpression["k=" <> ToString[a] <> ", n=" <> ToString[a],      TeXForm, HoldForm]];
myplot2[5, 4]
```

and lots of variations. None worked.

[image]

Or keep getting error messages,

> > ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse k=5, n=5 as input.

**GhostScript** (can't not configure properly)

[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to install `MaTeX`? `TeXForm` byitself does nothing. It just gives the latex representation of a Mathematica expression. To render it, you need to compile the latex, which is what `MaTeX` does.

Comment: @Nasser hmmm, tried it once. Seemed pretty difficult to setup. I have `MikTeX` on system, which supports `GhostScript`. but `MaTeX` still couldn't use it.

Comment: @Nasser I even give the full path `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin` which contains `gswin64c.exe`. and it still says not properly configured ... very annoying.

Comment: there's very detailed documentation--hope you used the doc centre as instructed. I  really dont know how to make config instructions any clearer. *Specific* suggestions for improvrments always welcome but please do read the config tutorial in full first

Comment: open doc centre and search for "matex" then see the configuring matex link. Suggestions will be incorporated into next version to make things easier

Comment: @Szabolcs not sure what you are referring to here. But regarding the configuration, the manual only says about the folder, which does not work on windows machines, it has to link to the specific EXE file, instead of the folder containing it ( which is what the manual says )

Answer (score 1):

Install [tex2im](http://www.nought.de/tex2im.php) (have a look a the **[options]**), then use this function

```
showTeX:=Import@ReadString["!tex2im -f png -o "<>#1<>" '"<>#2<>"';echo -n "<>#1]&[CreateFile[],First@#]&
```

with a TextCell as input, i.e. press Ctrl+9 and put your TeX commands that yellow/orange background box. In this way you won't have to bother with the escape characters that might be present in your TeX string. For instance, the FullForm of your input might be

```
showTeX[TextCell["\\sum_{n=0}^2 \\beta_n"]]
```

[image]

By pressing Ctrl+9 you do not need type those double backslashes "\"

Regarding your specific issue, `showTeX@TeXForm[..]` works as well because TeXForm is a wrapper similarly to TextCell.

```
myplot2[a_,b_]:=Plot[a*Sin[b*x],{x,-Pi,Pi},PlotLabel->showTeX@TeXForm["k="<>ToString[a]<>", n="<>ToString[a]]];
myplot2[5,4]
```

[image]