# Problem with exporting PlotLabel using MaTeX in Parallel computation

Tags: export, parallelization, labeling, latex

Requires `MaTeX`, which can be found [here](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

```
<< MaTeX`

myplot[k_: 5, n_: 10] := Plot[k*Sin[n*x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}    , PlotLabel ->     MaTeX["k=" <> ToString[k] <> ", n=" <> ToString[n],      Magnification -> 1.5]];
myplot[]
```

Works fine.
[image]

But if I export the PDFs using `ParallelTable`,

```
ParallelTable[ Export[ToString[n] <> ".pdf",    myplot[RandomReal[{-3, 3}], RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]], {n, 1,    30}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The labels fail to work.

[image]

Anyone had similar problems ?
Solutions?

Comment: As mentioned in Details of `ParallelTable`: The default value is `DistributedContexts:>$DistributedContexts` with `$DistributedContexts:=$Context`, which distributes definitions of all symbols in the current context, **but does not distribute definitions of symbols from packages**. So `DistributedContexts->All` should work.

Comment: @xzczd I looked at the `Help` and did `DistributedContexts->All`, didn't work.

Comment: @xzczd I think it might have something to do with `LaTeX` rather than `MaTeX`.

Comment: Without MaTeX: `PlotLabel ->  showTeX@TeXForm["k=" <> ToString[k] <> ", n=" <> ToString[n]]`, with `showTeX`  discussed here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178440/texform-as-plotlabels-configuring-ghostscript/178467#178467

Comment: You need to explicitly load packages on parallel kernels if you want to use thrm. See ParallelNeeds.  I can't type well due to a wrist problem so no full answer--sorry

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks and Take care!