# How to properly write fraction in style

Tags: string-manipulation

I would like to write the following for the legend of a curve :

$$ Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Where the value $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is actually in a variable named $Theta$ (same name as the text on the lhs of the equality). Of course, I don't know in advance that $Theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$). Also, I need to add some style to my text (like making it bold, increasing its size etc), this is why I am using the function Style as below.

However, when I write this in Mathematica :

```
Style["Theta=" <> ToString[Theta]]
```

The fraction goes under the $Theta$ like in this picture :

[image]

What can I do to make Mathematica write properly what I want? I am looking for a very simple solution.

Comment: Have you seen [MaTeX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/76943#76943)?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) (and especially, don't use a single argument [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString)). Instead, just use expressions instead of strings:

```
Subscript[θ,n]==π/2
```

[image]

**Addendum to address updated question**

Again, don't use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString). Here is how I would create your legend:

```
θ = Pi/2;
Style[HoldForm[θ] == θ, 20]
```

[image]

*(Note that legends in plots are by default displayed in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), so that the double equal symbol gets rendered as a (long) single equal.)*

Comment: Ok, I edited with further details. Actually the value $\pi/2$ is in a variable name that is the same of the text I want to write on the lhs. And I also want to add some style on my text (making it bold, bigger), so I think I can't really use a mathematical expression. The purpose is the legend of a graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(n\)]\)= \!\(\*FractionBox[\(\
\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\)"]
```

It is simplest to compose your text using the Basic Math Assistant palette.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I edited with further details. Actually the value π/2 is in a variable name that is the same of the text I want to write on the lhs. And I also want to add some style on my text (making it bold, bigger), so I think I can't really use a mathematical expression. The purpose is the legend of a graph.