# Modify Axes Range

Tags: plotting, graphics

With the following code:

```
arc = Graphics[{Arrowheads[{0, 0.04}], 
    GraphicsComplex[
     Table[{0.5 + 0.7 Re[Exp[I*g]], 0.5 + 0.7 Im[Exp[I*g]]}, {g, 
       Subdivide[0, Pi/2 - Pi/6, 100]}], Arrow[Range[101]]]}];
sensor = Graphics[
   Circle[{0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3], 0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3]}, 0.03]];
sensorM = 
  Graphics[Style[Text["M" , {1, 1.47}], FontSize -> 18, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
Omega0 = Graphics[
   Style[Text[
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(0\)]\)" , {0.2, 
      1.27}], FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
OmegaE = Graphics[
   Style[Text[
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(e\)]\)" , {0.8, \
-0.27}], FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
theta = Graphics[
   Style[Text["\[Theta]" , {1.2, 0.77}], FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
rpolar = Graphics[
   Style[Text["r" , {0.85, 1.17}], FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
er = Graphics[
   Arrow[{{0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3], 
      0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3]}, {0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3] + 0.3 Cos[Pi/3], 
      0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3] + 0.3 Sin[Pi/3]}}]];
etheta = Graphics[
   Arrow[{{0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3], 
      0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3]}, {0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3] - 0.3 Sin[Pi/3], 
      0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3] + 0.3 Cos[Pi/3]}}]];
erUnit = Graphics[
   Style[Text[Subscript[OverHat[e], r], {1.25, 1.55}], FontSize -> 20,
     FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
erthetaUnit = 
  Graphics[Style[Text[Subscript[OverHat[e], \[Theta]], {0.75, 1.65}], 
    FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
h = Graphics[
   Line[{{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}, {{0, 1/2}, {1, 
       0}, {0, -1/2}}, {{1, 1/2}, {2, 0}, {1, -1/2}}}]];
propVector = 
  Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{Automatic, Automatic, h}}], 
    Arrow[{{-1., 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}]}];
lines = Graphics[{Line[{{-0.8, 0.2}, {-0.8, 0.8}}], 
    Line[{{-0.75, 0.2}, {-0.75, 0.8}}]}];
pinc = Graphics[
   Style[Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(inc\)]\)", {-0.95, 0.75}], 
    FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]];
Show[{Graphics[{Dotted, Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 1]}], 
  Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.5]], arc, sensor, sensorM, Omega0, 
  OmegaE, theta, rpolar, er, etheta, erUnit, lines, propVector, pinc, 
  erthetaUnit, 
  Graphics[{DotDashed, Arrowheads[0.04], 
    Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3], 0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3]}}]}]}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontColor -> Black], 
   Style["y", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
    FontColor -> Black]}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.05}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I produced the following image

[image]

Eventually, I will get rid of `AxesTicks`, but I leave them for reference. I am puzzled how I can modify the Axes Range. For instance, the x-axis should range from -0.3 to 1.3 and similarly for the y-axis. The `AxesLabel` should be moved accordingly but the rest of the figure should not be modified.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `PlotRange -> {{-.3, 1.3}, {-.3, 1.3}}`, and add the option `ImagePadding -> Scaled[.1]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot! But now, unfortunately, one of the vertical lines on the left disappears.

Comment: @kglr If we modify the `Scaled` to 0.15 we get the whole figure but minimized I have to add `ImageSize -> 400` to get a bigger Figure but I do not know if this is the proper technique.

Comment: dimitris, i posted an answer using an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the axes and add the arrow and text primitives in the desired location:

```
Show[{Graphics[{Dotted, Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 1]}], 
  Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.5]], arc, sensor, sensorM, Omega0, 
  OmegaE, theta, rpolar, er, etheta, erUnit, lines, propVector, pinc, 
  erthetaUnit, 
  Graphics[{DotDashed, Arrowheads[0.04], 
    Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3], 0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3]}}]}]},
  Graphics[{Arrowheads[{0, 0.05}], Arrow[{{-.3, .5}, {1.3, .5}}], 
   Arrow[{{.5, -.3}, {.5, 1.3}}], 
   Text[Style["y", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
      FontColor -> Black], {.5, 1.4}],
   Text[Style["x", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
      FontColor -> Black], {1.4, .5}]}], 
 Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I use Mathematica a lot for visualisations but I am wondering if a Figure like the current could pass the typical journal publication requirements.

Comment: @dimitris, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. It looks better than many pictures I have seen in quite a few journals:)  If you haven't already seen it you will find Szabolcs's `Matex` package very useful ( [see this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943/125))

Comment: Actually I found Szabolc's package several minutes before posting my question. I saw the description and the download page but I was very tired to try it:-)! Thanks in any case because I was not familiar with the linked question!

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the same a what kglr posted, but it is structured so that making adjustments to the axis graphics is easy. In particular, using `Offset` makes very easy to adjust the position of the axis labels, since the adjustment is made in printer's points and thus independent of the coordinate system.

```
axes =
  Module[{axesLblF, xAxisPts, yAxisPts, xLbl, yLbl},
    axesLblF = (Style[#, 20, "TR"] &); 
    xAxisPts = {{-.3, .5}, {1.3, .5}};
    yAxisPts = {{.5, -.3}, {.5, 1.3}};
    xLbl = Text[axesLblF @ "x", Offset[{10, 0}, xAxisPts[[2]]]]; 
    yLbl = Text[axesLblF @ "y", Offset[{0, 10}, yAxisPts[[2]]]];
    Graphics[{Arrowheads[{0, 0.05}], Arrow[xAxisPts], xLbl, Arrow[yAxisPts], yLbl}]]

Show[
  Graphics[{Dotted, Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 1]}], 
  Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.5]],
  arc, sensor, sensorM, Omega0, OmegaE, theta, rpolar, er, etheta, 
  erUnit, lines, propVector, pinc, erthetaUnit,
  Graphics[
    {DotDashed, Arrowheads[0.04], 
     Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5 + 1. Cos[Pi/3], 0.5 + 1. Sin[Pi/3]}}]}],
  axes,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Note: I use the Times Roman font ("TR") because I do not have "Latin Modern Roman" on my system.